# Lista de comentarios para ayudar a los nuevos usuarios

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Creo este hilo porque **[JuanM ♦](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m)**, me preguntó cómo podríamos ayudar mejor, y después de un rato se me ocurrió que se podría crear un hilo en el que tener varias repuesta que incluyan comentarios genéricos y así sólo se tendría que entrar en el hilo y copiar el más adecuado en base a la pregunta del usuario. Por ejemplo, si es una mala pregunta en general se podría usar algo así:

---

**Para preguntas mal formuladas en general**

> Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto
> https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta
> mirando este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es
> posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

---

copiando lo anterior y publicándolo como comentario para la pregunta en cuestión y para el resto, por ejemplo las que son basadas en opiniones, las que son muy amplias, etc, se podrían agregar en este hilo en forma de respuestas.

Espero se entienda lo que quiero decir, con lo que hace mas fácil el ayudar a los usuarios nuevos, sin tener que reescribir una u otra vez lo mismo, o buscar en algún comentario que tu hayas dejado para copiarlo y ponerlo en esa respuesta,

> "esto puede llegar a ser muy pesado, me baso en mi experiencia"

de esta forma sabrías dónde están los comentarios genéricos para cada caso, y con el tiempo, las preguntas que contengan los comentarios genéricos se podrían editar para mejorarlos y dejarlos bien definidos.

> si te preguntas, si pero es que cuando se cierra ya aparece algo que
> lo orienta, eso es verdad pero, se a dado el caso en que la propuesta
> para cierre no sucede en varias horas o dias, y el usuario sigue
> publicando preguntas y puede pasar bastante tiempo hasta que se entera
> o se le orienta de alguna manera, y lo que ello con lleva el no saber
> como funciona el sito, por otro lado no todas la preguntas tiene que
> ser cerradas, puede darse el caso de que se le quiera explicar por
> ejemplo, que no deje el log en el comentario, o que no deje su una
> aclaracion como una respuesta, sino que edite la pregunta, y se
> podrian crear comentarios genericos tambien para estos caso, por
> ejemplo que explique de forma breve como editar una pregunta o como
> formatear el codigo ect.

Saludos

---

**Actualización:**

> Esta parte se podría usar para poner los títulos que enlacen con las respuestas en este hilo, por ejemplo:

Para aclaraciones, posible motivos del cierre o ayuda con la pregunta en general (lista):

- [Preguntas - Para preguntas mal formuladas en general](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/482#482)
- [Preguntas - Para preguntas formuladas en ingles](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/483#483)
- [Preguntas - Para preguntas falta de contexto **mcve - tour - How to Ask**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/1565#1565)
- [Preguntas - Para preguntas que son ejercicios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4144/324)

---

- [Preguntas - Basadas en opiniones **- que pueden tener acogida en el chat.**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/557#557)
- [Preguntas - Como demasiado amplia de responder en este formato Q&A](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/476#476) <kbd>no se ha creado</kbd>
- [Preguntas - Que no entran dentro de la temática del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/476#476) <kbd>no se ha creado</kbd>
- [Preguntas - Que no está claro lo que se pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/481#481)

---

- [Orientación - Para que sepa cómo formatear su código | "código en comentario"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/477#477)
- [Orientación - Para que sepa cómo formatear su código | "pregunta con mal formato de código"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/478#478)
- [Orientación - Para que sepa cómo y que puede editar su pregunta | "y no publicar una respuesta para aclara alguna cosa"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/479#479)
- [Orientación - Que es preferible en la medida de lo posible que deje un log de texto y no una imagen del mismo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/480#480)
- [Orientación - Marcar respuesta como aceptada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/1701#1701)
- [Orientación - Vandalismo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4145/324)

---

- [Duplicados - El usuario realiza una pregunta duplicada, sobre una
  pregunta que él/ella ya ha creado recientemente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/484#484)
- [Duplicados - El usuario realiza una pregunta duplicada, que ya ha sido creada y tiene o no respuesta en el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/476#476) <kbd>no se ha creado</kbd>

> **Actualización** Nota: Esto no trata de crear un standard, sobre cómo deben de ser
> los comentarios, solo es una lista de plantillas, para intentar ayudar
> a los nuevos usuarios, e intentar hacer más cómodo el publicar
> comentarios repetitivos para los usuarios que quieren explicar o
> aclarar alguna situación que se repite constantemente, sin que la
> calidad del comentario sea afectado por las ganas/tiempo del que lo
> publica.
>
> **Actualización** Nota1:
> También es posible que quiera usar una plantilla pero no le guste
> poner Saludos, basado en el ejemplo anterior pues puede simplemente
> adaptar ese término a la hora de publicar el comentario, para cambios
> mínimos

Comment: Ua pregunta ¿por que? todos tienen la frase _puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar_

Comment: @jasilva gracias por preguntar, es porque algunos usuarios nuevos no saben que se puede editar una pregunta, y lo de compartir .... reportar es para que se fije que eso es lo que ve justo debajo de su pregunta, mi intencion es que le sea facil de encontrar, pero si tu crees que es mejor indicarlo de otra manera puedes editar las que creas pero recuerda que los comentarios tienen un limite. Saludos

Comment: @jasilva creo que voy a añadir ...puede ver debajo de su pregunta compartir... tu que crees asi es mas facil? jaja todos no seria que las que habia creado coincidian en eso. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Ok, es que considero, para algunos casos de abajo bastaria con _puede editar_ pero me gustaria que mas chicos dieran su opinion antes de hacer un ajuste :)

Comment: @jasilva puedes poner si quieres abajo donde aparece compartir.. ect date cuenta que no todo el mundo entiende igual. Puedes editar o crear las que quieras las que yo cree son wiki, asi que sin problema, tambien hay otras que no he creado siente libre de crearlas si quieres o añadir alguna a la lista, fijate que las tengo separadas por grupos y para que sea mas facil de ver Saludos

Comment: @jasilva voy a poner una V al lado de las que tienen titulo pero no esta creada la respuesta haci creo que sera mas facil de ver cuales no esta con una platilla, una vez que se cree la respuesta pues se borra la V. update puse no se a creado en lugar de la V Saludos

Comment: @jasilva acabo de ver tu comentario para la pregunta en ingles igual tu puedes crear una repuesta aqui para esa clase de ocaciones. Saludos

Comment: Sé que esto tiene la intención de ayudar a la gente, pero lo que yo veo es que hay principalmente 2 tipos de usuarios nuevos: 1) Los que crean su cuenta para aprender y apoyar a la comunidad con sus preguntas y respuestas y se dedican a aprender cómo funciona la comunidad y se vuelven miembros de la comunidad, 2) Los que solo quieren que les resuelvan su pregunta y no les importa el resto del mundo, usualmente son los usuarios joker ([referencia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6AvTAKvK2IQ)). Y siendo honestos, en el sitio en inglés y acá en español hay más jokers...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza me parece buena tu idea, pero me surge la duda de si entendera que existe un boton para ello, pero si usted cree que es mejor y mas facil y no le importa añadirlo usted con una edicion, pues si le digo la verdad nunca en enlazado una palabra con un link, en un comentario y no se ahora mismo como se hace. Gracias por su aporte Saludos

Comment: Existe dicho enlace, se llama *editar*, pero por mi experiencia en ambos sitios los usuarios nuevos **simplemente no lo ven** por ello se los remarco en el comentario

Comment: [Acá un ejemplo](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4931/227) de lo que te comento.

Comment: Hola. Por tratarse de plantillas, me parece que en cada respuesta debería incluirse texto listo para copiar y pegar, por ejemplo, 1. lugar de usar formato de cita, usar formato de código 2. en lugar de usar URL usar magic-links cuando sea posible

Comment: @Rubén no se si te entendi, pero en la pregunta tienes unos link por ejemplo -> Preguntas - Para preguntas mal formuladas en general. que al hacer click te lleva a la respuesta que tiene el molde, pero no se si te refieres a eso, luego copiar lo que esta en sombreado y listo. Saludos

Comment: En mi comentario previo me refiero a la redacción en cada respuesta. Ya hice algunas ediciones, aplicando parcialmente esto : por ejemplo, http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/481/65

Comment: @Rubén te refieres a que este como codigo y no con el sombreado que esta es lo que vi que cambiaste ademas de los magic, si a mi me da igual mientras sea comodo. Saludos

Comment: Sí, a eso me refería :)

Comment: @Rubén si quieres puede añadir las que creas o las que uses si no estan en la lista las añades puedes ver debajo en la pregunta **Actualización:** mas o menos como estan organizadas, siente libre de añadir las que tu creas que sean utiles, ya sea para usted o para otros. Saludos

Comment: @Rubén es posible hacer algo como esto. un magic link por ejemplo que yo ponga [mal formulada] y salga la respuesta entera, espero explicarme bien, seria guay porque solo con unas palabras clave se pondria el comentario entero.Saludos

Comment: Sé que eso es posible mediante scripts de usuario, complementos, entre otras cosas. Creo que en https://stackapps.com/ se pueden encontrar este tipo de cosas, pero hoy en día no uso "nada de eso" :)

Comment: Si tenemos una lista para comentar según el caso de preguntas , por que no de respuestas ? , creo que también el sitio debería fomentar esto.

Answer (score 6):

**El usuario realiza una pregunta duplicada sobre una pregunta abierta recientemente**

> Hola $Usuario realizaste recientemente una pregunta sobre el mismo tema, no
>   es necesario abrir otro hilo, lo recomendable es editar la pregunta
>   original para agregar todos los detalles necesarios para resolver tu
>   problema. Puede hacerlo presionando sobre editar bajo su pregunta.

Comment: @AngelAngel Me parece totalmente correcto :)

Comment: Sería mejor no mezclar tratamiento tipo tuteo ("habías") con tratamiento tipo usted ("puede").

Comment: @Pablo que tal asi

Answer (score 5):

**Pregunta con falta de contexto (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example...ect)**

> Hola @User. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Creo que una
>   pregunta de este estilo, sí bien es totalmente válida, podría dar un
>   poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte).
>   Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco
>   contexto. No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese
>   fragmento, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo.Te recomiendo
>   [editar](/edit) la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el
>   [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). La idea es ofrecer un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) en todas las preguntas.

```
Hola @User. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Creo que una pregunta de este estilo, si bien es totalmente válida, podría dar un poco más de información a quien quiera ayudarte (ayudanos a ayudarte). Para alguien que no está en tu lugar, la pregunta da muy poco contexto. No explica qué se está haciendo ni de dónde salió ese fragmento, ni por qué estás interesado en entenderlo, ni nada que nos de alguna pista del objetivo. Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de esto, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.
```

Comment: @Mariano una pregunta porque lo pones como `codigo` y no como sombreado, ami me da igual solo es una duda porque Ruben tambien lo esta poniendo asi.Saludos

Comment: @Mariano yo lo digo por ponerlos todos igual si usted prefieren asi ponerlos todos asi. Saludos

Comment: Dejé ambas. Como código me parece la única forma en la cual alguien puede copiar correctamente los magic links, para que luego textos como `[edit]`, `[tour]` y `[mcve]` se conviertan en [edit], [tour] y [mcve] (bueno, este último funciona en el sitio, no en Meta)

Comment: @Mariano nada pues se ponen asi, es que via a Ruben tambien asi y no sabia el porque, borro el de arriba entonces, gracias por la aclaracion. Saludos

Comment: creo que es mejor dejar ambos... Así se ve cómo queda, y está el texto para copiar

Comment: @Mariano buena idea, para ver como queda, ya borre pero hago un roll

Answer (score 4):

**Para preguntas formuladas en inglés**

> Hi, $User! This site is purely in Spanish, consider translating
>   your question into Spanish or migrating it to the site in English [so].

---

Magic-links

- [so] -> https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: En este caso, ¿además se debería o no marcar como pregunta fuera de tema que corresponde a [so]?

Answer (score 3):

**Preferible log de texto y no en imagen**

> Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de
>   lo posible que deje un log de texto y no una imagen del mismo, pues
>   hace mas fácil su lectura para los usuarios, puede ver compartir,
>   editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre
>   el, y cambiando la imagen por el log de texto. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Preguntas basadas principalmente en opiniones **que pueden tener acogida en el chat**:

> Hola . Lamentablemente, este tipo de preguntas tan abiertas y que se prestan al intercambio de opiniones no son bien recibidas en el sitio. Sin embargo, puedes acceder al [salón de chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde esas preguntas son bienvenidas puesto que el chat es más informal y las personas cuentan sus opiniones sobre diversos temas. Solo haz click en el enlace de este comentario.

Comment: Creo que sería una buena propuesta a la hora de que uno ve una pregunta que se basa en opiniones.

Answer (score 3):

**Marcar respuesta como aceptada**

> Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes marcarla como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) dando click en el icono de `aceptar(check)` que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta que elijas. Toma en cuenta que esta es una comunidad de programadores y en el futuro podría ser de gran ayuda.

Para que pueda escribirse como comentario (inline link), el formato es el siguiente:

> Si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes marcarla como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) dando click en el icono de `aceptar(check)` que aparece al lado izquierdo de la respuesta que elijas. Toma en cuenta que esta es una comunidad de programadores y en el futuro podría ser de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

**Código puesto en el comentario**

> Acabo de editar su pregunta para añadir el código que usted dejó en el
>   comentario, observe que ahora está diferente, puede puede ver bajo su
>   pregunta compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a
>   editar presionado sobre él, y poner o modificar su pregunta para
>   añadir algo en este caso el código, le recomiendo que entre para que
>   pueda ver como se formatea el código, básicamente es poner 4 espacios, pero
>   lo puede hacer seleccionando el código en el modo edición y pulsando
>   sobre el icono `{ }` que está en la parte superior donde escribe el código, para
>   futuras preguntas/respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

**Vandalismo**

`Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Publicando en la red [SE] otorgaste derechos no revocables, bajo la [licencia CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) para que SE pueda distribuir su contenido. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/).`

Answer (score 1):

Si has llegado desde el link de la pregunta, a esta respuesta, es porque algun usuario plasmo la idea para crear un comentario generico, en el cual añadio este enlace para que no se mostrara la sintaxis, el cual aun no se a creado una respuesta siente libre de crear una respuesta para este enlace:

Notas: Recuerda que los comentarios tienen un limite de caracteres, puede seguir este estilo para tu respuesta ("el estilo no ha sido definido, es solo un test"):

---

> Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto
>   https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su respuesta
>   mirando este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es
>   posible que su pregunta sea cerrada.

Answer (score 1):

**Para añadir mas información a su pregunta, no en una respuesta**

> Para añadir mas información a su pregunta, puede ver bajo su pregunta
>   compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar
>   presionado sobre el, y modificando su pregunta, puede copiar el
>   contenido de su respuesta, y pegarlo dentro de su pregunta, después
>   puede eliminar esta respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

**Para preguntas mal formuladas en general**

> Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto
>   https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta
>   mirando este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es
>   posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**No está claro lo que se pregunta**

```
Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto [tour], puede 
tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link [ask], es posible que su pregunta sea 
cerrada o puesta en espera no se lo tome a mal para mas información vea 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions . Saludos
```

---

Magic-links

- [tour] -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour
- [ask] -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: me parece que se podría resumir mas.. y el link "tour" debería ser comentado en otro tipo de preguntas en mi opinión

Answer (score 0):

**Preguntas sobre ejercicios**

`Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.`

Answer (score -5):

**Pregunta con mal formato de código**

> Su pregunta no cuenta con un buen formato en el código, puede ver bajo
>   su pregunta compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a
>   editar presionado sobre el, modificar el código para darle formato,
>   puede hacerlo fácilmente básicamente es poner 4 espacios, pero lo
>   puede hacer seleccionando el código en el modo edición y pulsando
>   sobre { } que esta en la parte superior donde escribe el código.
>   Saludos

Comment: Esto no me parece tan problemático. Es muy fácil ayudar a indentar el código para que tenga el formato requerido para el sitio. No significa que siempre debamos indentar todo el código escrito en la pregunta para que sea 100% legible o facilite su lectura.