# Veo muchas publicaciones malas y me enoja muchísimo. ¿Qué debo hacer al respecto?

Tags: discusión, votos, votos-de-cierre, comentarios

Últimamente se han generado varias publicaciones (preguntas, respuestas, comentarios), principalmente preguntas, de muy baja calidad y que afectan a [las estadísticas del sitio como propuesta en Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) y no nos permiten salir del beta.

Casos de este tipo de publicaciones:

- Preguntas con escasa información. Ejemplo: "Hola. Necesito hacer `foo` con `bar`. Gracias."
- Preguntas de *hazme la tarea*. Ejemplo: "Tengo este ejercicio: < texto del ejercicio >. Saludos.". Este punto tiene una pregunta asociada en meta: [Preguntas de "¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/588/227)
- Preguntas de *te pago por resolverme el problema*. Ejemplo: "Buenos días/buenas tardes/buenas noches. Tengo un problema. Pago muy bien a quien quiera ayudarme a resolverlo. Me pueden contactar a < teléfono >. Muy agradecido."
- Respuestas que deberían ser comentarios. Ejemplo: "Por favor provee más información para ayudarte", "Necesitas brindar el stacktrace para ayudarte", "Sé que en mi equipo funciona".
- Respuestas que son solo enlaces. Ejemplo: "Ese problema lo explican aquí: http://sitioexterno.com/blog/entrada/3147/06/19/la-respuesta-esta/en-alguna-parte/de-todo-el-texto.html. Espero te sirva, saludos."
- Respuestas que son otras preguntas sobre el mismo tema. Ejemplo: "A mí también me sucede el mismo problema. Hice lo que decían en otras respuestas pero no funciona. Ayuda pliz."

Ver este tipo de cosas en el sitio hacen que mis ojos sangren. He participado en la comunidad en inglés https://stackoverflow.com y cuando veo publicaciones de ese tipo no pasan 5 minutos y ya están cerradas y hundidas a negativos. A veces me da coraje no tener la suficiente reputación y permisos para borrar sus publicaciones de la faz del sitio, así que me conformo con votar negativo y votar a cerrar pero siempre me persigue ese fantasma de que debí haber hecho más para que no ocurran estas publicaciones. La verdad últimamente me molesta cada vez más entrar al sitio y ver esta pobreza en la que nos estamos sumiendo. Inclusive a veces siento que no debería participar más, que debería dejar mi cuenta allí y olvidar todo...

¿Qué debo hacer al respecto como usuario?

---

Este tema ha salido como base a las conversaciones hechas en la [sala de chat del sitio](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol). Es un cúmulo de ideas, opiniones y otros puntos de vista encontrados allí. Exagera un poco en el caso pero esas son las sensaciones y preocupaciones que se detectan de los usuarios.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Primero que nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No dejes que lo que suceda en el sitio te afecte personalmente. Al final del día, solo es un pedazo de texto escrito en una página en internet. Brinda tu grano de arena en lo posible, y luego continúa con tu camino.

Yo creo que podríamos tener un pequeño sistema de cómo lidiar con esas publicaciones. Aquí dejo [unas ideas que comenté en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30099768#30099768):

- Preguntas de usuarios nuevos: poner comentarios para que mejoren su publicación. **No votemos a cerrarla ni votar en contra** en su primer día, de esa manera los ayudamos. Luego de emitir el comentario, sigan con su camino. Si el usuario responde negativamente al comentario, no le respondan con otro comentario para iniciar una guerra, solo pónganle una bandera (flageen) la pregunta y que el moderador se encargue.
- Respuestas de usuarios nuevos: si es un comentario en forma de respuesta, lo flagean y siguen con su camino. Si responden negativamente, idem al item anterior.
- Publicaciones de usuarios experimentados: votar a cerrar, se recomienda poner un comentario.
- Publicaciones de usuarios que deben dar el ejemplo: votar en negativo, quizás poner un comentario.
- Publicaciones que no se entienden porque simplemente no comprendemos del tema: Recomiendo dejarla tal cual. Si, por ejemplo, veo una publicación en [r](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) y no conozco del lenguaje ni plataforma ni información en absoluto, me parece que no tenemos la autoridad ni para votar en negativo ni para votar a cerrar.

Leyenda:

- Usuario nuevo: rep ∈ [1 .. 20] y por lo menos 2 preguntas sin cerrar y/o 2 respuestas sin eliminar.
- Usuario experimentado: rep > 100.
- Usuario que debe dar el ejemplo: rep >= 1000.

> He participado en la comunidad en inglés https://stackoverflow.com y cuando veo publicaciones de ese tipo no pasan 5 minutos y ya están cerradas y hundidas a negativos

Calma. **Esta es la comunidad en español**, no la comunidad en inglés. Nosotros tenemos nuestras propias reglas, como comunidad estamos para definir las reglas a utilizar aquí. El sitio en inglés tiene una gran cantidad de usuarios, por ello son más estrictos y agresivos. No tiene que ser igual aquí. Considero que seamos más pacientes por ser una comunidad mucho más pequeña. Además, esta paciencia hará que atraigamos más a los usuarios educándolos. Sin embargo, como pueden ver, si los usuarios no quieren prestar atención, no tienen que lidiar con eso, acudan al moderador porque esa es parte de su labor: pelear contra los malos.

Comment: Ok, ok. Tendremos paciencia. Pero si no funciona: http://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/3/39/Hank_Scorpio.png ;P

Comment: Por lo general, intento editar algunas preguntas para generar una redacción sin errores ortográficos que a su vez, mejora la lectura y comprensión de la misma; en caso de que no pueda entender de qué se trata la pregunta, opto por dejar un [comentario](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/475/78) y/o reporto aquellas preguntas según lo amerite.

Comment: @Mauricio me gusta tu idea. Podrías colocarla en una respuesta para que sea más fácil de leer.

Comment: Esto a mí ya me tiene literalmente cansado. Ahora sólo entro a revisar las 20 publicaciones que se cierra al día...

Comment: Hola @dwarandae. Te recomiendo que no lo tomes a mal. Si quieres, podemos conversar al respecto en el chat

Comment: Yo presuntamente soy usuario experimentado al tener una reputación superior a los 100 puntos; sin embargo me regalaron 101 puntos al registrarme (por haber participado en otros SE) y pese a que el resto me los he ganado no me considero experimentado en **este** sitio. *Cada SO tiene sus normas* y aún estoy adaptandome a las normas de este. Ciertamente, experimentado o no, quiero que este SO triunfe y estas preguntas me sacan de mis casillas.

Comment: disculpa pero en lo personal haré uso de mi derecho de hacer down vote, porque en el sitio en ingles me dieron down vote a mis primeras preguntas que sin saber eran de baja calidad y de esa manera aprendí... pero siempre intento adjuntar un link en comentarios a la seccion de ayuda para que aprendan como deberia ser formulada de mejor manera su pregunta... :) @LuiggiMendoza no es ser agresivo desde mi punto de vista, mas bien, es señalarles que esa pregunta puede ser mejorada (para el propio bien de quien pregunta)

Comment: @Hector Comprendo, aunque el sitio en inglés difiere mucho del sitio en español. Si tu decisión es ser agresivo para que los demás aprendan, lo respeto aunque no lo comparto en absoluto.

Comment: No creo que un "down vote" sea agresivo. Se puede votar negativo y dejar un comentario (amable) sobre por qué se hizo y sería correcto

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro uno solo no, el problema es que varios ven esa actitud y la imitan y la publicación termina inundada en negativos y sin comentarios, tal cual sucede en el sitio en inglés. Yo lo digo porque participé en otra comunidad asociada a los idiomas inglés y español y aunque publiqué una pregunta malísima para el sitio porque iba en contra del reglamento directamente **en ningún momento** obtuve ni votos en contra ni votos de cierre, un moderador fue lo suficientemente amable de decirme "estás violando las reglas, por favor revisa esto" y arreglé mi situación.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza pero entonces estás intentando "educar" a la persona equivocada. El que votó negativo la primera vez (idealmente con comentario para que OP aprenda) hizo las cosas bien. El problema son los borregos que imitan el voto negativo sin aportar nada más

Comment: Aparte, aunque votar en contra no es algo que me termine de convencer (le gente vota en contra y luego no revisa si la pregunta cambió, dejándola con un voto negativo que ya no merece), no me parece mal votar para cerrar la pregunta: una vez que 5 personas votan para que se cierre la pregunta, ésta realmente no se cierra; se pone "en espera" y se le muestra un mensaje al usuario indicando por qué está en espera y qué debe hacer para que sea reabierta. Puede que un comentario de otro usuario sea más efectivo, pero el mensaje por defecto de SOes debería considerarse suficiente.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro creo que la reacción del voto en contra y cierre sin comentario es como acercarte a alguien que hace algo "mal" por desconocimiento, darle una bofetada con una mirada de odio y luego irse sin decir nada. Y los usuarios primero ven "nadie puede responderme, no sé qué hice mal y ya estoy en problemas" antes de tan siquiera leer la causa que se explica en el motivo de cierre (suele suceder mucho). Sea que ahora dice "en espera" y no "cerrado", la idea central sigue siendo la misma: no pueden publicar respuestas a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Luiggi Totalmente de acuerdo contigo excepto en la última frase. Si una pregunta se pone "en espera" es porque tiene deficiencias considerables, no cumple con el mínimo exigido para estar en el sitio, y no debería tener respuestas hasta que dichas deficiencias sean corregidas. El mensaje de cierre de SOes explica los motivos y qué debe hacerse para que la pregunta alcance esa mínima calidad exigible; si el usuario no lee el mensaje y no realiza ninguna acción para solventar el problema, no se ajusta a las reglas del sitio, y entonces no es que no se pueda publicar respuesta, es que no se debe

Answer (score 5):

Como dicen en Area51, mucha gente entra a SO a través de un buscador, sin conocer nada de cómo funciona. Anda buscando una solución rápida para su problema para, sólo si no encuentra lo que busca, animarse a probar suerte poniendo una pregunta, lamentablemente sin cuidar de que tenga la calidad aceptable.

Pero sí que habría algo que podría ayudar a mejorar la calidad: **realizar preguntas con autorespuesta** que puedan servir de *modelo* para futuros usuarios. Posiblemente sea mejor opción que esperar a álguien haga la *pregunta perfecta*.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de preguntas con autorespuesta? Creo saber a qué te refieres, pero no estoy seguro del todo.

Comment: No es que conozca muchas, pero te puedo poner una que hice yo sobre [un fallo del instalador conda en windows](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5331/despu%C3%A9s-de-actualizar-conda-python-da-un-error-vcruntime140-dll-is-missing)

Comment: Vale, era exáctamente lo que creía; me ha pasado más de una vez por la cabeza pero hacerlo creía que me haría quedar como egocéntrico... pero también tiene la interpretación de pregunta-respuesta útil.

Comment: En realidad, la autorespuesta es algo a lo que se anima desde la FAQ: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4):

Por lo general, intento editar algunas preguntas para generar una redacción sin errores ortográficos que a su vez, mejoran la lectura y comprensión de la misma; en caso de que no pueda entender de qué se trata la pregunta, opto por dejar un [comentario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/475/78) y/o reporto aquellas preguntas según lo amerite.

Se esperaría que el nuevo usuario comprenda que hay un esfuerzo elaborado para ayudarle no solo a solucionar su problema actual, sino para además generar preguntas y respuestas de calidad que den valor agregado al sitio.

Answer (score 4):

Yo pienso que ante preguntas tan **absurdas** que tienen respuesta usando cualquier buscador, se debería cerrar sin más, eso está claro, pero además, que se le informe al usuario la razón del cierre, la **incongruencia** de su pregunta y además, se le invite a leer las FAQ y reglas cordialmente. Obviamente, todo esto por parte de la **moderación** y como un inbox.

Bombardear al OP con votos negativos sin más, es como decirle *"Eres un tonto, tu pregunta es muy mala"* y aunque sea cierto, no es la forma. Si al usuario no le interesa en lo más mínimo aprender cómo funciona el sitio, a realizar preguntas de forma inteligente (que por cierto todo foro de programación te exige, no solo SOF), pues se le puede banear luego de un pasar un límite de ese tipo de preguntas.

Answer (score 2):

Yo te quiero comentar algo:

Yo he encontrado preguntas como [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7230/problemas-al-mostrar-un-archivo-pdf-en-el-navegador/) donde la pregunta me pareció bien planteada y la duda y todo bien. Esta pregunta era sobre FPDF en PHP. Sin embargo todos empezaron a decir que la actualizará y que estaba mal. Y los moderadores la iban a poner en espera con sus votos. Afortunadamente alcance a responder antes de que eso pasará. Y no es lo único que he visto, la mayoría las he dejado pasar sin responder. A lo que voy es que esto también pasa en el sentido inverso. **A veces una pregunta bien planteada pero muy especializada es cerrada porque los moderadores no conocen el tema**. Eso por un lado.

Por otro lado cuando yo veo una [muy mala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13262/cuales-son-las-principales-librer%C3%ADas-java-para-el-uso-en-redes/) pregunta generalmente la dejo pasar y cuando no lo hago, generalmente contesto solo código. ¿Por que lo hago? *Para obligar a quien pregunto a investigar*. **Cada vez que solucionas los problemas de alguien que no se esfuerza, piensa en que el día de mañana puede llegar a ser tu compañero de trabajo, o peor, tu jefe**. Muy buena frase del usuario **Xerelo** en foros del web.

Una ultima cosa, generalmente los moderadores pasan aquí todo el día, no se si hagan otros desarrollos, pero por la cantidad de respuestas que dan, parece que solo se dedican a esta página y eso esta bien, es su trabajo. Pero mucha gente que entra aquí no es su trabajo de diario, vienen a resolver una duda y no vuelven a entrar en días, semanas o hasta que tienen algún rato libre. Por eso en ocasiones se da la idea de como resolver una duda, y no lo respuesta completa, como [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559/guardar-sharedpreferences-asignandole-una-key/), ese día no tenía mucho tiempo pero quería ayudar y alguien mas termino por responder mejor. **Pero quien pregunta también debe poner de su parte y ponerse a investigar ¿No crees?**

Comment: *A veces una pregunta bien planteada pero muy especializada es cerrada porque los moderadores no conocen el tema* concuerdo contigo al 100%. También me da coraje cuando una pregunta es cerrada y cuando veo a quienes votaron para cerrarla no participan en esas etiquetas en absoluto, lo cual me dice "¿y quiénes son ellos para votar a cerrar una pregunta solo porque no la entienden ni entienden las tecnologías/temas asociados al respecto?"

Comment: *Cada vez que solucionas los problemas de alguien que no se esfuerza, piensa en que el día de mañana puede llegar a ser tu compañero de trabajo, o peor, tu jefe* sí, puede pasar (nos guste o no). Por ello, debemos tratar de apoyar a que las preguntas mejoren su calidad. Sin embargo, no significa que debas proveer malas respuestas. Sería mejor proveer comentarios a respuestas malas, o quizás no proveer nada en absoluto.

Comment: *generalmente los moderadores pasan aquí todo el día* no es correcto, hay días donde yo personalmente entro 1 o 2 veces y solo para atender banderas, en otras oportunidades participo más activamente. *es su trabajo* al igual que cualquier usuario, los moderadores somos usuarios colaborativos. **No es nuestro trabajo**. Es un esfuerzo personal y el compromiso es propio de cada moderador, no recibimos ningún pago ni estamos afiliados de alguna manera con StackOverflow como empleados ni de otra manera.

Comment: *Pero quien pregunta también debe poner de su parte y ponerse a investigar ¿No crees?* sí que lo creo, por ello promover educar a los usuarios mediante comentarios apuntando a los enlaces de ayuda del sitio. Eso no justifica que seamos tan severos con ellos como para espantarlos. No en una comunidad que busca crecimiento y es más la gente que asusta que la que se queda. "Calidad no significa cantidad" puedes decir, pero no podemos ir a ninguno de los extremos.

Comment: Con respecto a los moderadores yo no afirme, si te das cuenta puse "parece", no era algo que yo conociera. Y no hay que molestarse por eso, ni tomarlo personal. 
Yo no considero que cuando pongo código sea una mala respuesta si el código funciona, o resuelve el problema no creo que sea mala respuesta solo por no tener explicación. 
Tampoco considero haber sido severo con alguien o espantarlo, para ello creo debí haberle dicho insultos, groserías o tomándolo personal. Cosa que creo que no he hecho en ningún momento.
Te invito a que observes como se comportan los moderadores de foros del web.

Comment: En foros del web tambien mucha pregunta de ese tipo. Donde te das cuenta que el que pregunta no quiere buscar o quiere que le hagan la chamba. Pero generalmente ese tipo de preguntas se deja que se pierdan en el historial. Y ahi los moderadores no se molestan porque respondan solo código.
Me gusta en general más como se comporta la gente en ese foro aunque considero que en este hay mas nivel.

Comment: Aunque como dices, si "no es nuestro trabajo" no habría porque tomarse tan personal, porque generalmente quien hace ese tipo de preguntas va en los 1ros semestres de la carrera que no sabe todavia como es esto, o es gente que no tiene deseos de superación y considero que los que invierten su esfuerzo en responder, no deben
rebajarse al nivel de los que no se quieren superar.