# ¿Qué utilidad tiene esta página?

Tags: soporte

Desde el principio que entré en esta página me dió bastante pánico. Y ahora que llevo un tiempo en esta veo los siguientes fallos:

1. **Te borran las preguntas.**  Está bien que borren una pregunta duplicada o irrelevante. Pero de ahí a borrar cualquier pregunta que hagas por el simple hecho de la ignorancia parece un poco arrogante ¿No os parece?.

   **Usuarios descaradamente arrogantes.**  Se la pasan tirando tus preguntas y respuestas abajo y reportándolas. Te las editan incitándote al suicidio. Lamentablemente esto es mejor que youtube en cuanto a eso, pero se agradecería mejor gestión, argumentando los puntos en contra, por ejemplo. ¿Acaso es tan difícil?

   **Mala estructura.**  La estructura de preguntas y respuestas es pésima. No puedes crear una sala de chat de la nada, tiene que ser en una pregunta. Si se te clona estás perdido. Aparte, no puedes comentar en una pregunta de otro porque requiere que tengas un apoyo personal de 50, y ya sabemos cómo está el tema de las puntuaciones. Todo se solucionaría si se pudiesen crear salas de chat y reportar como se hace actualmente. Y en lugar de preguntas los usuarios pudiesen hablar con la gente que conoce de sus temas.

En fin, stackExchange me ha decepcionado como Youtube. No volveré a estar activo en ambas exceptuando si es para votar una respuesta aquí, o un vídeo en youtube. Generalmente opino que el internet en general es una porquería como la humanidad en sí.

Comment: Intenta participar con respuestas en vez de tantas preguntas.

Comment: @ArtEze no tiene **nada de malo** solo participar con preguntas. Eso es aceptable. Lo principal es participar dentro de la comunidad.

Comment: Nota para quienes votaron en negativo: en realidad solo refuerzan el contenido de la sección 2 de tato. Por lo menos brinden un comentario.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No es malo, pero en este caso, creo creo que el usuario le parece que este sitio es malo porque no experimentó las diversas cosas que se pueden hacer.

Comment: @Tato, lamento que tu experiencia sea tan mala, en realidad el sitio es bastante bueno para los objetivos planteados.

Comment: Volví, no veo páginas mejores que esta...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza
Un momento ¿Se supone que esto es una página de preguntas y respuestas?

Comment: Así es. No es un foro ni un (micro)blog ni una red social ni nada por el estilo. Es un sitio donde publicas preguntas y recibes respuestas. Puedes obtener más información si revisas el [tour].

Comment: :/
guzgarcía dice que ciertas preguntas no se pueden hacer en este sitio...

Comment: Así es también. Hay muchas preguntas que podemos tener como ¿quiénes somos? ¿de dónde venimos? ¿cuál es el propósito de nuestra existencia? ¿por qué [42 es la respuesta a la última pregunta de la vida, el universo y el todo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29)? etc. Pero eso no significa que podamos preguntar cualquier cosa aquí. De hecho, te convendría revisar [ask] para comprender mejor el tipo de preguntas aceptadas en el sitio.

Comment: Ya paso de usar esta página. Es lo que dice guzgarcía. Sería más aparente Yahoo answers, y eso que no estoy conforme con esta última.

Comment: Bueno, es decisión tuya. No podemos decirte si continuar participando o no. Pero recuerda que eres bienvenido en la comunidad para seguir participando con tus publicaciones. Pero si infringes las reglas, atente a las consecuencias.

Comment: Pido disculpas por lo que hice, pero creo que una discriminación por minusvalía no ayuda en nada al sitio (Siempre que la persona se esfuerze claro).

Answer (score 27):

> **1. Te borran las preguntas**

Veo que tienes 3 preguntas que tú mismo las has borrado:

- [Error inexplicable con php al intentar hacer un chat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/30982/227). Me parece que algunos usuarios se sienten ofendidos con el uso de la palabra "mierda" para los nombres de tus archivos. En lo personal, yo no porque la computadora lo interpreta y puede hacerlo funcionar. Pero no todos los usuarios piensan igual.
- [¿Cómo se hace un chat con RTCpeerconnection?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/28333/227). Creo que aquí el título no está acorde al cuerpo de la pregunta. El título se asocia a una pregunta demasiado amplia, mientras que el cuerpo indica "¿por qué no se dispara el método `webkitRTCPeerConnection#onmessage` cuando ?". Adicional a esto, hay un comentario tuyo que me parece un poco ofensivo: "Además estamos hablando de WebRTC, no cambies de tema". La parte final puede considerarse rudo, te recomendaría tener más cuidado en ello.
- [¿Cómo usar RTCpeerConection?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/27664/227). La pregunta parece bien formulada. Quizás no recibió la atención suficiente y por eso la borraste.

En resumen, no te borran las preguntas, quizás las mandan a cerrar. Es frustrante al comienzo, pero te pregunto: ¿Has leído la [sección del centro de ayuda sobre preguntas cerradas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)? ¿Qué has hecho al respecto? No veo ediciones posteriores tuyas a tus preguntas luego de haber sido cerradas, lo cual me dice como si solo te enfocaras en que la cerraron pero no en el por qué.

> **2. Usuarios descaradamente arrogantes**

Lastimosamente, estamos en internet, y cualquier persona tiene libertad de expresión y puede escribir lo que quiera, nos guste o no. Cuando encuentres una situación donde te esté causando furor, lo mejor que puedes hacer es permanecer calmado y reportar la publicación que te dificulta. Esto se cubre en más detalle aquí: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/616/227. Te pediría que coloques ejemplos para evaluarlos aquí en meta a nivel de comunidad y en conjunto veamos cómo proceder.

Parte de lo que mencionas: "[Las respuestas] las editan incitándote al suicidio", creo que haces alusión a [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31506/227). El usuario [P. Flanderson](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19990/p-flanderson?tab=profile), por la descripción en su perfil, se puede notar que es un usuario troll y que solo quiere causar caos. Nuevamente, no permitas que ese tipo de usuarios ni sus publicaciones te molesten. Repórtalos y continúa con tus cosas.

Considera que como moderador tenemos más poderes en el sitio, pero no significa que estamos viendo todas las publicaciones antes de que aparezcan. Es por ello que ustedes, los usuarios, pueden reportar las publicaciones que consideren inapropiadas para el sitio. Asimismo, puedes publicar preguntas en meta para discutir alguna publicación (pregunta, respuesta, comentario).

> **3. Mala estructura**

En detalle:

- "La estructura de preguntas y respuestas es pésima". He visto que tienes varias publicaciones y algunas con respuestas útiles. No creo que este sistema no funcione, hay que revisar las reglas del centro de ayuda para que resulte más efectivo para ti y para la comunidad.
- "No puedes crear una sala de chat de la nada, tiene que ser en una pregunta". [Puedes crear salas de chat una vez que alcances 100 de reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms). Antes de eso, si necesitas una sala de chat, puedes reportar una pregunta y solicitar que un moderador la cree por ti.
- "Si se te clona estás perdido" ¿Clonar qué? Si es por la pregunta (preguntas duplicadas), diría que no estás perdido, ya se trabajó en otra pregunta y puede que contenga más información de la que buscabas y sea provechoso para ti. Si te refieres a la cuenta, entonces informa con un reporte para que puedan unir tus cuentas.
- "Aparte, no puedes comentar en una pregunta de otro porque requiere que tengas un apoyo personal de 50, y ya sabemos cómo está el tema de las puntuaciones". Esto es decisión del sitio, y se explica [aquí](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/182862). Solo traduciré la primera parte de la respuesta aquí (lo haré luego en otra publicación):

> La historia y la experiencia han demostrado las desventajas de permitir que cualquiera pueda comentar son más grandes que unos pocos comentarios perdidos:
>
> - Existen grandes problemas con el spam. Los filtros automatizados no pueden capturarlos a todos.
> - Incluso entre los comentarios reales, la mayoría dirían "Tengo el mismo problema" o "Estoy de acuerdo". Estos comentarios no agregan valor, y deben ser eliminados manualmente.
> - Los comentarios son muy dolorosos de moderar. Los sitios de Stack Exchange tienen un proceso de moderación comunitaria (votar, reportar, colas de revisión) que funciona muy bien para las preguntas y respuestas, pero no tanto para los comentarios. Los comentarios no se pueden votar en contra o para ser cerrados, tampoco se pueden buscar (ni queremos eso).
> - Los comentarios son ciudadanos de segunda clase en la red de Stack Exchange, no están diseñados para mantener información por toda la eternidad. Ellos pueden ser limpiados en cualquier momento. Generalmente, la información realmente importante debería estar incorporada dentro de una respuesta en sí misma.

Sobre la historia de las puntuaciones, yo la verdad no sé. Cualquier usuario (con la reputación necesaria) puede votar a favor o en contra de las publicaciones. Si brindamos publicaciones de calidad en el sitio, es muy probable que los votos vayan a favor. También he visto publicaciones que considero malas con votos a favor, pero no hay nada que pueda hacer, esto depende enteramente de la comunidad.

- "Todo se solucionaría si se pudiesen crear salas de chat y reportar como se hace actualmente. Y en lugar de preguntas los usuarios pudiesen hablar con la gente que conoce de sus temas".

Ya se habló previamente sobre las salas de chat. Siempre puedes reportar las publicaciones y los moderadores revisarán los casos puntualmente. Ahora, considera que el sitio busca que existan preguntas específicas y respuestas a estos problemas específicos, no intenta ser un sitio de discusiones largas y extendidas donde la respuesta a tu problema puntual está en medio de las 20 páginas de la discusión. En lo personal, esto me suele pasar cuando reviso listas de correos o conversaciones de chat de 10000 líneas o foros con 10 páginas de hilo y la respuesta específica que busco consiste en fragmentos de publicaciones de las páginas 2, 5, 6 y 9.

> stackExchange me ha decepcionado como Youtube. No volveré a estar activo en ambas exceptuando si es para votar una respuesta aquí, o un vídeo en youtube.

Siento mucho leer eso, pero la comunidad siempre estará dispuesta a ayudarte. Espero que en el futuro puedas volver y continuar contribuyendo con tus publicaciones.

> Generalmente opino que el internet en general es una porquería como la humanidad en sí.

El sitio no puede ayudarte al respecto. Y nuevamente, puedes hacer uso de tu libertad de expresión para publicar tus ideas. Pero en este sitio hay reglas que deben respetarse, te sugiero evitar este tipo de comentarios en tus publicaciones porque serán eliminados.

Comment: Excelente respuesta Luiggi! +1

Comment: No sé, sí, tienes razón excepto en lo de comentar las publicaciones. Esto debería ser más abierto, cualquiera debería comentar a modo esquemático y con comentarios que equivaliesen a una pregunta. Eso sí, siempre respetando una integridad moral. Es demasiado obvio que me tomo los votos en contra como algo mucho peor de lo que es.

Comment: @TatoBroh la experiencia en los sitios de StackExchange ha demostrado que es mejor colocar ese nivel mínimo para los comentarios y es un estándar general. Me alegra saber que has visto esta respuesta y espero que vuelvas a participar en el sitio.

Comment: Si, pero cualquiera debería participar en los comentarios, y en lugar de puntuaciones deberían utilizarse marcas como "acoso", "duplicada", etc. para las preguntas, y para las respuestas en lugar de tirarlas abajo deberían permitir que en cada respuesta se pudiese comentar con un error de chrome bien probado, y que se pudiesen probar fácilmente los errores con un botón de ejecutar y capturar en la misma pregunta.

Comment: @TatoBroh la parte de comentarios está cubierta en el enlace que he provisto. Tal como se explica allí, esa regla es general para todos los sitios de la red StackExchange y estoy de acuerdo con ese pensamiento. Sino estaríamos inundados de comentarios que no son respuestas y no siempre tienen la calidad esperada de una respuesta.

Comment: @TatoBroh adicional, no todas las respuestas pueden ser probadas por errores de chrome. Empezando porque no todos usamos chrome, luego porque no todas las preguntas son de programación web, y porque hay preguntas que no son directamente de programación sino de diseño de software, configuración, etc.

Comment: Debéis mejorar. No solo el hecho de hacer más fácil preguntar, sino saber cuándo se debe aceptar una respuesta por válida, y potenciar la validez de las respuestas. Esta página está para enseñar a través de preguntas de manera autodidacta ¿Me equivoco en algo?

Comment: No entiendo....

Comment: Bueno, ya quedé bloqueado para hacer más preguntas. Supongo que tengo la obligación de retirarme. No defraudaré a nadie. Si así lo habéis querido es por algo...

Comment: Entiendo. Buena suerte en el futuro. A mí no me defraudas, por cierto.

Answer (score 10):

yo al principio pensé lo mismo que tu amigo pero al tiempo que estuve en esta comunidad aprendí una cosa muy importante a "preguntar correctamente" y a aclarar mi problema correctamente y viendo unas de mis preguntas pasada vi algo muy mal en mi, no sabia expresarme correctamente por eso motivo mi pregunta se parecía a otra y me la eliminaban pero después de este tiempo que e estado en estada comunidad  agradezco las reglas porque si no existiera este maravillo sitio se volviera un "yahoo respuesta"

Comment: No es fácil preguntar correctamente, y eso se echa en falta en esta comunidad. Debería ser fácil. Aunque gracias por tu aporte, siempre hay gente con cierta empatía.

Comment: @TatoBroh es muy facil. solo sigue: [ask]

Comment: @EndermanTesla denada, deberias entender que asi es este mundo y asi es el internet.

Comment: Pido disculpas por lo que hice, pero creo que una discriminación por minusvalía no ayuda en nada al sitio (Siempre que la persona se esfuerze claro).