# ¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?

Tags: soporte, faq, eliminación-de-preguntas, eliminación-de-respuestas

¿Qué circunstancias podrían hacer que una pregunta o una respuesta sean eliminadas, y qué es lo que implica?

- ¿Cómo puede eliminarse una publicación?
- ¿Cuándo *no podría* eliminar mi propia publicación?
- ¿Puedo ver la lista de mis publicaciones eliminadas?
- ¿Cómo puedo recuperar una de mis publicaciones eliminadas?
- ¿Qué *sucede* cuando se elimina?
- ¿Qué pasa con los votos de una publicación eliminada?
- ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?
- ¿Qué más debería saber acerca de la eliminación?
- Si reporto mi pregunta solicitando que se elimine, ¿qué pasaría?

> Para más información, lea la ayuda acerca de [preguntas eliminadas](/help/deleted-questions) y [respuestas eliminadas](/help/deleted-answers) en el [Centro de Ayuda](/help).

---

> Traducido de *[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/304899)*

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## ¿Cómo puede eliminarse una publicación?

#### Por un usuario registrado:

1. **El autor** puede eliminar sus propias publicaciones cuando desee. -Para ver las excepciones, lee *¿Cuándo* no podría *eliminar mi propia publicación?* más abajo. Para eliminar una publicación, simplemente haz click en el enlace *eliminar* debajo de la misma.
2. **Los moderadores** pueden eliminar cualquier publicación instantáneamente.
3. **Los usuarios con reputación ≥ 2k** (más precisamente, con el privilegio de [editar preguntas y respuestas](/help/privileges/edit); 1k en sitios en beta) [pueden generar](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/304899) una eliminación automática si eligen *recomendar eliminación* dentro de la cola de revisión de baja calidad.
4. **Los usuarios con reputación ≥ 10k** (más precisamente, con [acceso a herramientas de moderación](/privileges/moderator-tools); 2k en sitios en beta) pueden votar para eliminar *preguntas* que han estado [cerradas](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/304899) por al menos 48 horas. Se necesitan tres votos para eliminar, o [más si la pregunta es popular](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/304899), hasta un máximo de diez votos.
5. **Los usuarios con reputación ≥ 20k** (más precisamente, un [usuario de confianza](/privileges/trusted-user); 4k en sitios en beta) no están sujetos al período de espera de 48 horas para poder eliminar preguntas cerradas con una puntuación de -3 o inferior. También pueden votar para eliminar *respuestas* con un puntaje de -1 o inferior. Se necesitan tres votos para eliminar una respuesta.

#### Por el sistema:

6. [El sistema](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/304899) eliminará automáticamente toda aquella publicación [reportada](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22174/304899) seis veces como irrespetuosa o abusiva, o con contenido no deseado.
7. El sistema [eliminará automáticamente](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/304899) preguntas cerradas (no como duplicados), que no han sido [bloqueadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts), con una puntuación de cero o negativa, sin respuestas con puntaje positivo ni aceptadas o con votos de reapertura pendientes, que estuvieron cerradas por 9 o más días, y que no han sido editadas en los últimos 9 días.
8. El sistema [eliminará automáticamente](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/304899) preguntas sin respuestas, que no han sido [bloqueadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts), con una puntuación negativa luego de por lo menos 30 días.
9. El sistema [eliminará automáticamente](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/304899) preguntas que fueron migradas de otro sitio y rechazadas (cerradas, excepto por ser un duplicado) luego de por lo menos 30 días.
10. El sistema [eliminará automáticamente](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/304899) preguntas sin respuestas, que no han sido [bloqueadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts), con una puntuación de cero (o si la cuenta del autor fue eliminada), con un promedio de menos de 1.5 vistas por día, y con menos de dos comentarios luego de por lo menos 365 días. Esta regla aplica solamente al sitio principal, no a Meta.
11. El sistema [elimina automáticamente](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199860/304899) preguntas (y sus respuesta(s)) con un puntaje negativo cuando la cuenta de su autor es eliminada.
12. El sistema eliminará automáticamente preguntas migradas a otros sitios [luego de 30 días](//meta.superuser.com/q/9338/527470). Nótese que esto aplica exclusivamente a la copia local de la pregunta original, creada en el sitio inicial, no a la pregunta nueva creada en el sitio de destino como resultado de la migración. Las preguntas eliminadas automáticamente bajo este criterio, conservarán el historial de revisiones que será visible para todos, y los enlaces a éstas redireccionan a la nueva pregunta (no muestran la página de error).
13. Las publicaciones con puntuación de cero o negativa que reciben seis votos de *recomendar eliminación* en la cola de revisión de baja calidad son eliminadas automáticamente. Las publicaciones pueden entrar en esta cola ya sea automáticamente o por reportes de *muy baja calidad* o *no es una respuesta*, y pueden ser sacadas de la cola si juntan los suficientes votos de *se ve bien*.

    Además: *[El usuario "Comunidad" ha eliminado mi pregunta. ¿Qué pasó? (ROOMBA)](//es.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)*.

## ¿Cuándo *no podría* eliminar mi propia publicación?

No puedes eliminar *respuestas* que han sido [aceptadas](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/304899).

No puedes eliminar *tu propia pregunta* si:

- tiene una [respuesta con un voto a favor](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471/304899) (incluso si la puntuación total es negativa),
- tiene una respuesta aceptada,
- tiene una respuesta que [recibió una recompensa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306966/304899) (a menos que se elimine esa respuesta primero), o
- tiene múltiples respuestas (por más que no tengan votos a favor)

No puedes eliminar *ninguna* de tus preguntas o respuestas si no has ***registrado*** tu cuenta (asociándola con un OpenID).

## ¿Puedo ver la lista de mis publicaciones eliminadas?

Sí, pero sólo [publicaciones eliminadas que han sido **creadas en los últimos 60 días**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491/304899). Un listado completo de todas las publicaciones eliminadas [no será implementado](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/304899) (los usuarios con reputación ≥ 10k pueden además [buscar entre sus publicaciones eliminadas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145060/304899) utilizando `deleted:1`).

Sin embargo, si guardaste el enlace a tu publicación, podrás verla independientemente de tu reputación.

## ¿Cómo puedo recuperar una de mis publicaciones eliminadas?

Las publicaciones auto-eliminadas pueden ser recuperadas por el autor. Sin embargo, las preguntas auto-eliminadas no pueden ser editadas por su autor hasta que hayan sido efectivamente recuperadas. Las respuestas auto-eliminadas pueden ser editadas por su autor sin que haga falta recuperarlas. Normalmente, si no fuiste quien ha eliminado tu publicación, no podrás ser quien la recupere (aunque podrás votar para recuperarla). Una excepción es cuando una respuesta es eliminada desde la cola de revisión de baja calidad por votos para "Recomendar Eliminación", sin que hayan votado para eliminarla tres usuarios de confianza, entonces sí [puede ser recuperada](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/304899) por el autor.

Si tu publicación fue eliminada por [usuarios de confianza](/privileges/trusted-user), se necesitarán 3 votos para recuperarla -consultar educadamente en Meta puede ser suficiente para atraer los votos necesarios si es que se plantea bien el caso explicando por qué debería ser recuperada.

Si tu publicación fue eliminada por un moderador, puedes reportar otra publicación tuya con el motivo "se necesita la intervención de un moderador" y escribiendo una nota que explique la situación por la que se solicita la recuperación.

Si tu publicación fue eliminada por el usuario Comunidad, puedes [votar para recuperarla](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214252/304899).

Nota: las preguntas eliminadas no aparecen en los resultados de búsqueda, por lo que si tienes planeado recuperar más tarde una pregunta que eliminaste, deberías guardar la URL. Los usuarios con reputación ≥ 10k también pueden marcar estas preguntas como "favoritas" para encontrarlas luego en la pestaña de Favoritos, dentro de su perfil. Sólo los moderadores pueden buscar publicaciones eliminadas de otros, nadie más (los usuarios con 10k también pueden [buscar dentro de sus propias publicaciones eliminadas](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/145060/304899)).

Las publicaciones eliminadas que *no tienen más de 60 días* (desde la fecha de creación) están listadas dentro de las herramientas de moderación, en ["Eliminado recientemente"](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/304899).

## ¿Qué *sucede* cuando se elimina?

Las publicaciones eliminadas normalmente **no son** eliminadas físicamente (o sea, eliminadas del sistema). Simplemente están escondidas (*eliminación lógica*). Esto significa que no aparecerán en los resultados de búsqueda o en los datos exportados, y los usuarios comunes que intenten ir al enlace de esa publicación, verán una [página de error 404, explicando la causa de la eliminación](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1).

Los moderadores, y los usuarios normales con reputación ≥ 10k, pueden ver todas las publicaciones eliminadas para las cuales tienen los enlaces que los lleven. Los usuarios con menos de 10k pueden ver las publicaciones propias que han sido eliminadas. Los moderadores pueden recuperar cualquier publicación eliminada.

Los usuarios con 10k pueden votar para recuperar *preguntas* eliminadas: normalmente se requieren tres votos para recuperar, pero [pueden ser más](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/304899).

Los usuarios con 20k, también pueden votar para recuperar *respuestas*: se requieren tres votos para recuperarlas.

## ¿Qué más debería saber acerca de la eliminación?

- La reputación asociada a recompensas, votos (positivos y negativos), y las aceptaciones de publicaciones eliminadas (incluyendo respuestas a preguntas eliminadas) es anulada. (Excepciones: la reputación ganada por publicaciones con una puntuación de tres o más, cuando la publicación estuvo visible en el sitio por lo menos 60 días, [se mantiene](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), y si tuvo recompensas, [no son devueltas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306966/304899)).
- Si bien la reputación perdida por votos negativos se recupera, esos votos siguen contando hacia una posible [prohibición para publicar nuevas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited). Si publicaste una pregunta que no fue bien recibida por la comunidad, la mejor opción siempre va a ser editarla para mejorarla.
- La reputación perdida como penalidad por haber tenido una publicación eliminada por reportes no es devuelta.
- La primera vez que elimines una publicación propia con un puntaje de 3 o superior, ganarás la medalla [Disciplinado](/help/badges/37/disciplined).
- La primera vez que elimines una publicación propia con un puntaje de -3 o inferior, ganarás la medalla [Presión de pares](/help/badges/38/peer-pressure).
- Las respuestas son eliminadas automáticamente cuando la pregunta en la que se encuentran es eliminada. Esas respuestas también serían recuperadas automáticamente si se recupera la pregunta, excepto las respuestas que fueron eliminadas *antes* que la pregunta.

## ¿Qué pasa con los votos para eliminar o recuperar?

- Si ya puedes [votar para eliminar (parte del privilegio de herramientas de moderador)](/privileges/moderator-tools) (10k de reputación, o 2k en sitios en beta), tienes 5 votos de eliminación por día, [más 1 voto cada 1000 puntos de reputación por sobre los 10k](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/105876/304899) ([hasta un máximo de 30 votos por día](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/304899)). Los votos para eliminar tu propia publicación [pueden, o no, considerarse dentro de este límite](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274757/304899), dependiendo de las circunstancias.
- Obtienes la misma cantidad de votos para recuperar como los de eliminar.
- Los votos para eliminar o para recuperar nunca caducan.

## ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?

Para preguntas, una publicación [que ya no agrega *nada* al sitio](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/304899) debería eliminarse. Básicamente, incluye a la gran mayoría de las preguntas cerradas que no pueden ser mejoradas y reabiertas. Sin embargo, puede ser beneficioso mantener duplicados, como señalizadores aportando más términos de búsqueda -ayudando a usuarios que estén buscando una pregunta ejemplar.

Para respuestas, cualquier publicación que [no es una respuesta](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/304899) (debería ser un comentario, no responde a la pregunta, etc.) debería ser eliminada. Las respuestas que están equivocadas o que dan malos consejos deberían ser castigadas con votos negativos, pero no eliminadas.

## Si reporto mi pregunta solicitando que se elimine, ¿qué pasaría?

La política estándar para moderadores es la de declinar estos reportes. El razonamiento es el siguiente:

- si puedes eliminar tu pregunta (porque no tiene respuestas, o la única respuesta no tiene votos positivos), entonces tú deberías hacerlo. No requiere la intervención de un moderador.
- si no puedes eliminar tu pregunta, entonces debe haber una respuesta con votos positivos, o múltiples respuestas. Eliminando la pregunta, se eliminarían esas respuestas. Y eliminar esas respuestas anula al gran trabajo que otras personas han dedicado en responder, y también revierte la reputación que han ganado. Esto no sería justo para quienes respondieron tu pregunta.

Si publicaste una pregunta de la que te arrepientes porque:

- es una tarea escolar y has violado el "código de conducta" del establecimiento
- te da vergüenza porque es una pregunta tonta

entonces eliminarla no es la solución porque usuarios con 10k de reputación (2k en sitios en beta) igual la podrán ver. Además, [está claro en los términos de servicio (sección 2)](//stackexchange.com/legal) que:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the [Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content ...

Los moderadores no eliminarán tu pregunta por los motivos antedichos.

*¿Qué hago si publiqué código para el cual mi empleador tiene los derechos de autor, o en la que hay una violación a estos derechos, y por motivos legales debe ser eliminada?*

Stack Exchange impementa el proceso de baja, de acuerdo con el [DMCA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act). Si posees los derechos de autoría o reproducción, y alguien (un empleado?) ha publicado contenido que contaviene tu derecho, entonces puedes registrar una baja por derechos de autor y el contenido será eliminado. El proceso está [descripto en la sección 15 de los términos de servicio](//stackexchange.com/legal).

Reportar tu pregunta para la atención de moderadores no es el proceso indicado a seguir.

En cambio, puedes [solicitar que la publicación sea desasociada de tu cuenta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/304899).

*¿Qué hago si publiqué las credenciales de un usuario u otra información sensible?*

En ese caso, edita la publicación con datos genéricos que sigan manteniendo el mismo significado, manteniendo el mismo contexto (tanto la pregunta como las respuestas que lo usaron). Y luego de que lo hayas editado, reporta la publicación solicitando la atención de un moderador, para que puedan redactar el historial de revisiones.

*¿Hay excepciones?*

Muy ocasionalmente se hacen algunas excepciones. Muy a menudo, esas excepciones tienen lugar cuando:

- todas las respuestas tienen más de 60 días, no tienen puntaje o es bajo (las respuestas de más de 60 días no revierten la reputación cuando son eliminadas, siempre que posean un puntaje de 3 o más)
- hay algo sospechoso acerca de la pregunta y/o las respuestas, algo que no está cubierto en esta respuesta.

> Traducido de *[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/304899)*

Comment: Cito: `9. El sistema eliminará automáticamente preguntas sin respuestas, que no han sido **bloqueadas**`, ¿con bloqueadas se refiere a puestas en espera o cerradas?

Comment: Se han anunciado cambios en Meta Stack Exchange, específicamente en

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306966/289691

El "primer" cambio es acerca de la recompensas otorgadas en preguntas que han sido eliminadas. En este momento me parece algo complicado incluir la explicación. 

Otro cambio es que ahora si el autor de una pregunta ha otorgado una recompensa a una respuesta no podrá borrar la pregunta, a menos que la respuesta sea eliminada primero. Este sería más sencillo de incorporar, creo.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave : Me parece que a ninguna de las dos ya que bloqueadas es un concepto diferente. En español se explica en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2639/65

Comment: -1 `El autor puede eliminar sus propias publicaciones cuando desee`, eso es condicional, y aunque más abajo expliques los casos de cuando no pueden borrarse las preguntas, la afirmación es contradictoria, y además al ser lo primero que se lee puede causar confusión.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz me parece una ridiculez votar negativamente a una publicación wiki de Meta en la que alguien ha traducido altruistamente una información que estaba en inglés. Puedes patalear, pero también apostar por ser productiva: mejora la traducción (¡es wiki!) si es lo que pica, o bien sugiere con una [meta-tag:característica-nueva] que Stack Exchange gestione este tema de otra manera.

Comment: No entiendo por qué molestarse en responderme, precisamente para eso es Stack Overflow Meta, para discutir.