# ¿Cómo puedo borrar una pregunta de Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: discusión

Quisiera saber cómo borrar una pregunta de esta página o por lo menos cómo borrar mi cuenta.

Comment: Para borrar la pregunta, puedes encontrar un enlace en la parte inferior de la misma. Y para borrar la cuenta, puedes encontrar la respuesta en el Centro de Ayuda en: [¿Cómo borro mi cuenta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

Answer (score 6):

En realidad haces dos preguntas en una, te respondo la primera.

Hay un link para eliminar la pregunta debajo de las etiquetas, que es visible si tu has realizado la pregunta.

[image: Eliminar pregunta]

Sin embargo, no podras eliminar una pregunta que tiene respuestas con votos a favor de la comunidad, ni si has aceptado una de estas respuestas.

Solo puedes eliminar la pregunta que no tiene respuestas con votos a favor.

Con información de [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033).