# ¿Deberíamos borrar las preguntas que "sobran" del sitio?

Tags: discusión

Realmente no vengo a crear un debate sobre que tipos de preguntas se deberían eliminar o no. Para eso ya está esta otra pregunta: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-eliminaci%C3%B3n-de-publicaciones-por-qu%C3%A9-podr%C3%ADa-eliminarse-una-p)

Con motivo de esto, creo que hay preguntas que no aportan nada al sitio y que deberían ser eliminadas. Adjunto solo preguntas en las que no hay respuestas totalmente válidas para no perjudicar a los usuarios que si que han respondido a las preguntas correctamente aunque las preguntas no se lo mereciesen.

Este es un muestreo pero podría listar muchas más:

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37762/software-de-gesti%C3%B3n-empleados
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37755/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-hacer-una-aplicaci%C3%B3n-en-android-que-haga-lo-siguiente
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38665/generar-n%C3%BAmeros-hasta-uno-dado-prolog/38678#38678
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39083/por-qu%C3%A9-se-muestra-los-elementos-en-el-fondo
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38098/como-puedo-realizar-un-analizador-sint%C3%A1ctico-ejemplo

Creo que este tipo de preguntas no aportan nada a la comunidad y deberían de ser eliminadas para limpiar el sitio de las preguntas que "sobran". Considero que es un sitio nuevo y esta labor no supone todavía mucho trabajo. Sin embargo, si lo dejamos para el futuro, y conforme el sitio se vaya haciendo más grande, supongo que será más difícil de gestionar.

**PROPUESTA:**

- En cuanto veamos una pregunta de este tipo, votar para cerrarla.
- Si ya está cerrada y han pasado varios días desde su publicación (dejemos al OP al menos un par de días para rectificar su pregunta), votarla negativo para que se pongan de las últimas en la cola de preguntas ordenadas por votos. Así será mucho más fácil llegar a ellas y proceder a su posterior eliminación.
- Revisar de vez en cuando la lista de preguntas filtradas por votos e irnos a las últimas páginas que serán las que más votos negativos tengan. Proceder al voto de eliminación de las preguntas que consideremos que no aportan nada a la comunidad.
- También nos podemos pasar por las herramientas de eliminación (`En Revisar --> Herramientas`) para ver cuales han sido las últimas preguntas/respuestas votadas para eliminar.

Por supuesto, esto solo lo podrán realizar los usuarios que hayan obtenido el privilegio de eliminar preguntas.

Creo que será muy beneficioso al sitio para no tener preguntas que básicamente es imposible que ayuden a nadie en un futuro (un enunciado de un ejercicio o una pregunta cuyo contenido sea "créame un erp" por ejemplo).

¿Qué opináis? ¿Deberíamos tener más en mente eliminar las preguntas inservibles? ¿O deberíamos dejarlas allí?

Comment: No es por nada amigo... pero si es así como describes, tendrías que ser el primero de no contestar a esas preguntas...=> *que no ayuden a nadie en un futuro*... y más si eres ya oficialmente un `trusted user` ...se que a veces esta la tentación de ganar reputaciones fáciles pero eso es ser en mi opinion un *vampiro* de reputaciones y creo que eso no ayuda a mejorar la comunidad... También estaba pensando de proponer a los moderadores de subir las reputaciones de los privilegios... en fin... todo esto es solo una opinion/sugerencia mía... P.D. No te he votado negativo en esto... Saludos

Comment: Hola @aldanux. Lo primero de todo, muchas gracias por el comentario. Sí, yo soy el primero que he pecado en responder en preguntas de este tipo, aunque creo que siempre han sido de carácter tipográfico. No sé si fuiste tu o Mariano (tenéis avatares parecidos) los que me avisasteis del error. Y a partir de ese momento he cerrado todas las preguntas (o al menos que me haya dado cuenta) y después votado para su eliminación. Y si hay más respuestas que consideras malas por mi parte no dudes en comentármelo y no dudaré en rectificar. De hecho, ya lo he hecho en más de una ocasión y las he borrado.

Comment: @aldanux Y yo también considero que deberían de subir los privilegios. Soy el primero que intenta que la comunidad crezca así que cualquier error que esté cometiendo me lo podéis indicar sin ningún problema. Creo que para eso existen los comentarios, para poder dar un punto de vista que igual el que pregunta/responde no ha tenido en cuenta.

Comment: Me la paso dando opiniones sobre lo que creo que _debería ser_ para que todo funcione mejor (está en mi naturaleza)… Ahora, de ahí a que tenga memoria para recordar lo que dije, ya es otro tema… ¡Lo que no puedo aceptar es que se confundan máscaras que [no tienen nada que ver entre sí](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/8d/29/fc/8d29fc42938695cca837bc7e806e93a1.jpg)!

Comment: @Mariano Una vez me fijo más detenidamente no hay confusión pero un poco sí cuando doy un vistazo rápido. Yo también me paso el día dando opiniones, e intentando ayudar, somos de naturaleza altruista ;)

Comment: Juas... :) Estuvo bueno de las máscaras.. pero yo.. ehm...digo mi mascara ... al menos sonríe...

Answer (score 4):

Yo creo que las preguntas deberían seguir su curso. Si la pregunta es mala entonces eventualmente será cerrada y tendrá puntaje negativo. Si es mala y el OP no la edita para mejorarla, al cabo de 9 días será eliminada por el sistema, tal como se explica en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1034/227), en el punto 7. El cumplimiento de los otros puntos también es importante, pero en el caso que mencionas, se trata más sobre el punto 7. Dejemos que el sistema se encargue de eso, y listo. Darle un esfuerzo mayor para ello quizás no sea lo más adecuado.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. Todos los días me canso de ver preguntas que deberían tener puntajes negativos o estar flaggeadas y veo en específico a un usuario con un muy alto puntaje contestando lo que se le atraviesa como si sólo le importara tener un +1. Se que el sitio apenas comienza pero el grado de la gran mayoria de preguntas es deplorable y en muchos casos un outsourcing del problema.

Comment: @Chisko reporta la pregunta. Cuando yo, como moderador, veo estos casos, tiendo a borrar la pregunta.

Comment: Estoy formulando una pregunta al respecto. Pronto aparecerá en el feed.

Comment: @Chisko el tema de aquí se trata de preguntas malas que no han recibido respuestas. Eso se demuestra por los ejemplos que publica Error404. Sobre ellas, el sistema ya las borra, no hay nada adicional qué hacer.