# ¿Cómo eliminar una pregunta que ya tiene respuestas?

Tags: soporte, eliminación-de-preguntas

¿Cómo puedo hacer eliminaciones de preguntas que yo tengo y que tienen una respuesta?

En algunas ocasiones no aportan nada a la comunidad. Por ejemplo,  tengo dos o tres preguntas mías en Stack Overflow en español donde aparentemente tenía un error de programación, pero al ir indagando me doy cuenta que es un error tipográfico (o como coloquialmente se le dice "erro de dedo") dentro de mi código, por lo cual creo que sería conveniente hacer la eliminación de dicha publicación.

Ya di clic en la opción que dice "eliminar", pero me dice que no se puede porque tiene respuestas. Entonces ¿es posible borrarla? o ¿tengo que esperar a que la cierren?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No se puede.

Si una pregunta tiene:

- una única respuesta y esta tiene un puntaje positivo, o
- más de una respuesta

entonces no se puede eliminar.

Esto es así para evitar el abuso del sistema por parte de quien pregunta: imagina que preguntas, la gente se toma un tiempo en responderte y en ese momento borras la pregunta arrastrando con ello la/s respuesta/s. Feo.

Si la pregunta no tiene razón de estar por ahí, el sistema Roomba se encargará de eliminarla pasados unos días si no tiene un mínimo de visitas y votos .

Esto está explicado con profundidad en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/83).

Comment: ¿Qué es el sistema Roomba? ¿Es el usuario Comunidad?

Comment: @Flxtr es la máquina de limpieza de [se]. Básicamente un algoritmo que borra preguntas si no supera un mínimo de votos y visitas. En [cómo funciona la eliminación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/83) se explica muy bien. Por ejemplo, borra preguntas con puntaje 0, no cerradas y con dos o menos comentarios si tiene menos de 2 visitas al día.

Comment: ... y, al ser un proceso periódico, se puede ver en acción en las [herramientas de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), observando las últimas publicaciones eliminadas y la hora en la que ocurre cada eliminación.

Comment: En un par de ocasiones me ha pasado que publiqué una respuesta que solucionaba el problema y el OP borró la pregunta al poco tiempo, tal vez porque consideran que ya no es necesaria al estar solucionada, o porque lo resolvieron por su cuenta. ¿En ese caso la única opción es nominar la pregunta para ser "recuperada"?

Comment: @Shaz antes de nada, uno debe preguntarse si valía la pena responder. Si ed así y la respuesta vale la pena, yo animo a luchar por recuperarla. Dado que es difícil recuperarlas actualmente (hay pocos >10K) sugiero traerlo a Meta para ser tratado.

Comment: En esos casos sí valía la pena responder, no eran preguntas / respuestas triviales, en próximas ocasiones las traeré a meta entonces (ya borré esos favoritos). Gracias por responder.

Comment: @Shaz teniendo como tienes reputación >10K, puedes encontrarlos. Busca algo así como `user:me is:answer deleted:yes score:0 [alguna_etiqueta]`.

Comment: @Shaz periódicamente reviso las preguntas que tienen votos para recuperar pero, como habrás visto, la interfaz en `/tools` no es de lo mejor que hay... Siempre está bueno llamar la atención sobre estos casos para que podamos ver la pregunta y evaluarla... Incluso puede ayudar un mensaje en el chat.

Comment: @Mariano yo sugiero utilizar Meta de momento, para crear cierta _jurisprudencia_.

Comment: @fedorqui por supuesto... No quería dar un método alternativo, sino complementar lo que dijiste. Meta es el lugar para esto, el chat puede ayudar a obtener un poco más de atención nomás. Igual Shaz dejó el chat hace bastante ya :-)

Comment: @Mariano estamos de acuerdo :) Por cireto, muy interesante el uso de [_igual_ como sinónimo de _a pesar de todo, no obstante_](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3189/1674).