# Información por traducir - What is a locked post?

Tags: soporte, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Dentro del centro de ayuda está un [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) que está en inglés bajo el título "What is a locked post?" que debería ser "¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?", además todo el contenido se encuentra en inglés.

Alguien que nos ayude para poder publicar esta parte del sitio en español.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ¿Qué es una publicación bloqueada?

Una publicación "bloqueada" no puede ser modificada por ningún medio. Bloquear una publicacion evita que...

- ...se vote en esta publicación (incluyendo cerrar/reabrir votos para preguntas)
- ...sea editada
- ...se realicen comentarios
- ...se responda (para preguntas)
- ...sea reportada (aunque los reportes de "se necesita la intervención de un moderador" se seguirán permitiendo, excepto en el caso de bloqueos de significancia histórica - ver abajo)

## ¿Quién puede bloquear una publicación?

Los [moderadores el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) pueden aplicar tipos específicos de "bloqueo" para la preguntas y respuestas.

También, el [sistema mismo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) bloqueará las publicaciones en determinadas situaciones:

- si la publicación es borrada, ya sea por ser reportada como ["spam" o "abusiva"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- si la publicación es migrada a otro sitio.
- si la publicación fue migrada *al* sitio actual y luego [rechazada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).
- si la pregunta fue unida en otra, las respuestas serán movidas y la pregunta    de origen será bloqueada.

## ¿Cuánto tiempo permanecen bloqueadas las publicaciones?

Esto depende de cómo fue bloqueada para empezar.

- Cuando un moderador bloquea una publicación, ellos tienen que seleccionar cuánto tiempo debería durar el bloqueo. Las opciones son: 1 hora, 1 día, 1 semana, o permanentemente. Concluido este tiempo, el sistema automáticamente la desbloqueará.
- Cuando el sistema bloquea una publicación se mantiene bloqueada indefinidamente - solo un moderador puede desbloquearla.

Un moderador puede manualmente desbloquear una publicación en cualquier momento si le parece necesario.

## ¿Cuándo debería ser bloqueada una publicación?

Por regla general, los bloqueos *temporales* deberían ser usados cuando modificaciones a la publicación están causando serios problemas en el sitio. Por ejemplo:

- [Guerra de ediciones](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)
- Discusiones extendidas en los comentarios (pero lee: [una guía sobre cómo moderar comentarios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments))
- Una publicación controvertida que se está discutiendo en meta

Los bloqueos *permanentes* casi nunca deberían ser usados, con la excepción de aquellos impuestos por el sistema en sí. Aunque hay dos excepciones:

- Una pregunta extremadamente popular que ahora se considera inapropriada para el sitio puede ser bloqueada por su "Importancia Histórica": esto altera la apariencia de la pregunta, automáticamente bloquea todas las respuestas también y deshabilita la opción de reportar completamente. Este bloqueo debería estar reservado para casos en los que un artefacto cultural y apreciado sería borrado; **no** lo uses para otro caso.
- Una "wiki" es una pregunta cuyas respuestas [pueden ser editadas por usauarios con poca reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), atribuida a múltiples usuarios y no da reputación al autor original. Son útiles en casos donde la información debe ser compilada por diferentes autores (por ejemplo, una lista de recursos o documentación del sitio en sí); en estos casos, bloquear la pregunta previene que sea cerrada y que más respuestas sean añadidas.

Ver también:

- [What is a "locked" post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) en Meta Stack Exchange
- [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) en Meta Stack Exchange
- [Advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)