# Cerrar una pregunta solucionada

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

En https://es.stackoverflow.com/ he realizado una pregunta. Tras el primer comentario que ha realizado un usuario, me he dado cuenta de que es un problema de conflictos de diferentes bibliotecas de javascript.

Al final, lo he solucionado usando otras bibliotecas y mi duda es la siguiente:

Nadie ha respondido a la pregunta, ¿borro directamente la pregunta? Era un [caso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96795/qtip-no-funciona-dentro-de-una-etiqueta-pre-code-b) muy específico y particular. En caso contrario, ¿cómo puedo marcarla como cerrada o que hacer en este caso?

Comment: Tal como está la pregunta, yo la borraría ya que no aporta nada a la comunidad.

Comment: De acuerdo, pensaba eso mismo, me precipité un poco en hacer la pregunta en lugar de investigar antes probando sólo con los scripts necesarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este sitio, las preguntas de calidad no se cierran salvo que se vuelvan obsoletas, el cierre es para preguntas de baja calidad o que tratan sobre cosas que no corresponden a la temática de este sitio.

En el caso de preguntas sobre problemas que el autor ha encontrado la solución por su cuenta pueden ser respondidas por el mismo autor y en el caso que se identifica que era una mala pregunta y que no tiene sentido mejorarla, el autor tiene la opción de borrarla por el mismo o dejarla a que sea borrada por alguien más, lo cual en ciertos casos podría tardar varios meses. Más detalles en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/65)