# ¿Por qué no puedo eliminar una pregunta con recompensa?

Tags: soporte, recompensas, respuesta-propia

Al parecer nadie podia responder a mi pregunta. Esperaba una súper explicacion detalladisima a [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114926/mal-manejo-de-eventos-sfml) de por qué mi programa no podía manejar eventos correctamente. Pero veo que nadie en la comunidad pudo ayudarme. Al final, luego de leer exhaustivamente la documentación ilegible... pude entender que los eventos se sincronizan con el sistema y que mi programa explotaba era por falta de eso.

En fin, pude resolver mi duda. Hasta respondi con un comentario (creo que era lo correcto) pero ahora el sistema me está obligando a dar la recompensa que ofrecí, la cual nadie merece.

¿Esta bien que la web no permita eliminar mi pregunta? Ya que nadie sabe de sfml pienso que es redundante dejarla alli. Y por eso busco eliminarla.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aquí planteas distintas cosas:

> Esperaba una súper explicacion detalladisima a [mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114926/mal-manejo-de-eventos-sfml) de por qué mi programa no podía manejar eventos correctamente. Pero veo que nadie en la comunidad pudo ayudarme.

Por [lo que veo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/114926/revisions) ofreciste una recompensa de 50 puntos. Está muy bien y puede animar a la gente a mirar con más cariño tu pregunta, pero tampoco es que tiraras la casa por la ventana :)

Además, tuviste a [uno de los mejores expertos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2742/paperbirdmaster) del sitio consultándote en comentarios pero tampoco clarificaste demasiado sus dudas.

> ¿Esta bien que la web no permita eliminar mi pregunta?

Bueno, esto es el diseño actual. Cuando ofreces una recompensa estás "pagando" para que esté destacada. Esto tiene el efecto automático de que durante ese tiempo no se pueda cerrar, por ejemplo. Ni eliminar, por lo que comentas, que tampoco me parece mala idea: al fin y al cabo, puede que por estar destacada haya gente investigando al respecto.

> En fin, pude resolver mi duda.

Lo resolviste: ¡genial!

> Hasta respondi con un comentario (creo que era lo correcto)

No, lo correcto sería responder a tu propia pregunta. Es algo que no solo está permitido sino que se recomienda: [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) explica *¡Si! Stack Exchange [siempre ha alentado](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) a los usuarios a responder sus propias preguntas. Si tienes una pregunta la cual ya conoces su respuesta, y quisieras mantener un registro público de ese conocimiento de tal manera que otros (incluyéndote a ti mismo) puedan encontrarlo luego, es perfectamente aceptable hacer una pregunta y responderla tú mismo en los sitios de Stack Exchange.*

Comment: en reaidad habia respondido a mi propia pregunta pero pense que me banearian por hacer eso, asi que la elimne... gracias por aclarar todo

Comment: @RenatoA. al contrario, puedes incluso ganar [medallas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) por contestar tus propias preguntas.

Answer (score 4):

Como bien explica @fedorqui en su respuesta, si conseguiste resolver tu problema lo que deberías hacer es añadir una respuesta explicando cual es la solución y aceptarla posteriormente.

Entiendo que algunos nuevos usuarios no entiendan la filosofía de StackOverflow y no está de mas recordarlo las veces que haga falta. Continuamente se recuerda que StackOverflow **no es un foro**. Hay varias diferencias, y una de ellas es la causa por la que el sistema no deja eliminar las preguntas en algunas circunstancias.

Por decirlo de una forma sencilla, cuando alguien realiza un pregunta en el sitio, ésta **deja de ser propiedad del usuario** y pasa a pertenecer a la comunidad. Esto significa que si se dan ciertas circunstancias, la pregunta no podrá ser eliminada. Éstas están detalladas en [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/15301).Traduzco la parte que explica cuando no puedes eliminar tu propia pregunta:

> ## ¿Cuándo *no podría* eliminar mi propia publicación?
>
> No puedes eliminar *respuestas* que han sido [aceptadas](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/304899).
>
> No puedes eliminar *tu propia pregunta* si:
>
> - tiene una [respuesta con un voto a favor](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/74471/304899),
> - tiene una respuesta aceptada, o
> - tiene múltiples respuestas (por más que no tengan votos a favor)
>
> No puedes eliminar *ninguna* de tus preguntas o respuestas si no has
> *registrado* tu cuenta (asociándola con un OpenID).

En cuanto a las preguntas con recompensa esto es lo que se dice en [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> Las preguntas con recompensa no pueden ser eliminadas directamente
>
> Sin embargo, los moderadores pueden eliminar la recompensa, lo que limpiaría el historial de la misma. La reputación del propietario de la recompensa será recalculada como si nunca la hubieran ofrecido. Esto permitiría que la pregunta fuera cerrada, migrada o eliminada como cualquier otra pregunta.

No lo aclara exactamente, pero de aquí intuimos la razón de no dejar eliminar una respuesta con recompensa. El que ha ofrecido la recompensa (que no tiene por que ser el que realizó la pregunta) automáticamente perdió los puntos de reputación que ofreció, y estos no pueden ser recuperados en ninguna circunstancia a no ser que un moderador elimine (lógicamente con una causa justificada) la recompensa del sistema. Además (esto es una interpretación mía) se considera que una pregunta con recompensa puede ser interesante para otros usuarios (por ejemplo, para el que ofreció dicha recompensa), y por ello no se permite su eliminación.

En StackOverflow la comunidad está siempre por encima del usuario. Por ello, todo lo que se agrega pasa a formar parte de la base de datos de conocimiento global. Como dije antes, una vez creas un post en el sitio, debes tener en cuenta que deja de pertenecerte y pasa a pertenecernos a todos.

Comment: anda! no sabia que si los mods eliminamos la recompensa se devuelve al usuario que la ofreció. pense que estaba perdida esa rep

Comment: Solo en ese caso, que creo que no se da practicamente nunca. No se me ocurre en que circunstancia un moderador debería eliminar una recompensa @lois6b

Comment: a mi si https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/116018/editor-open-source-para-php-html-css-etc xD

Comment: ambas respuestas fueron exelentes, pero como dice en las reglas.. cuando ambas respuestas son muy buenas... gana el que respondio primero, muchas gracias por la informacion

Comment: No te preocupes @RenatoA. En meta "no gana nadie", lo importante es que tu duda haya sido aclarada :)