# Opción para descartar edición

Tags: discusión, soporte, característica-nueva

Un día hice una edición a una pregunta, el OP había añadido contenido pero como respuesta, así que decidí ponerlo en la pregunta, sin embargo me había equivocado y edité la respuesta. ¿Por qué no hay una opción para descartar una edición?, en mi opinión esto ayudará bastante, ya que a veces podemos equivocarnos en mucho. O tal vez tener una opción para volver a editar, esto antes de que la edición sea aprobada o rechazada.
Esto vendría bien ya que así se puede minimizar las colas de revisión,  además el editor tiene el derecho de poder descartar su edición antes de ser aprobada o rechazada, de la misma forma que una persona puede retractarse de un reporte.

Comment: Cuando tengas [suficiente reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) podrás [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) sin restricciones, tanto preguntas como respuestas. Mientras tanto, haces bien en reconocer errores en tus propias ediciones, te hace ver disciplinado, sigue así. Otros editores se encargarán de aprobar o rechazar tus ediciones hasta que ya puedas hacerlo por ti mismo. Es como las rueditas de la bici, al llegar a 2000 pts te las quitan. ;)

Comment: Ooo... ok, eso suena mejor y tiene más sentido, gracias por la info

Comment: A mi me pasó lo mismo que a ti. Precisamente edité la respuesta de alguien más pensando que era mi respuesta y que alguien la había editado. Lo que yo hice fue dejar un comentario en esa respuesta avisando de mi arrepentimiento al editar y me rechazaron la edición. Puedes hacer eso si tu propuesta no es aceptada. Sin embargo, yo estoy de acuerdo y creo que deberia de existir tal botón.

Comment: @Dante S. Exactamente, además de que así se podría minimizar las colas de revisión, en mi opinión las personas con menor reputación no podría hacer nada, además es la edición propia y deberían tener el derecho de poder descartarla antes de ser aprobada o rechazada.

Comment: Esa que están proponiendo, no es una mala idea...

Comment: @MauricioContreras tengo la duda. Cuando tienes menos de 2000 de reputacion, se hace lo que dices y te dan +2 de reputacion si se aprueba. Entonces cuando llegas a 2000 de reputacion, si editas, te siguen dando los +2?

Comment: @JuanRivera, pues no una vez que llegas a los 2000 de reputación ya no tienes +2 puntos por edición, pero si puedes perder 2 puntos si la publicación que editaste es eliminada.

Comment: @Israel-ICM interesante...pero en ciertos casos? Porque creo que no tendria sentido esforzarse en editar una publicacion para que el OP lo elimine y encima te quiten 2 puntos

Comment: @Israel-ICM es cierto  no creo que sea justo quitar 2 puntos por que la publicación haya sido eliminada, de todas formas se dedica tiempo a editar la publicación

Comment: @JuanRivera y Christian pueden encontrar mas información en esta publicación  [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-eliminaci%c3%b3n-de-publicaciones-por-qu%c3%a9-podr%c3%ada-eliminarse-una-p). ;)