# ¿Es posible recuperar una pregunta eliminada?

Tags: discusión

Elimine una pregunta que había sido resuelta en los comentarios, después pensé que no debí eliminarla porque alguien hizo un comentario y me ayudó en lo que buscaba hacer pero, la eliminé porque no me gustó la explicación cuando cerraron la pregunta, la pregunta que eliminé fue [Cómo cargar un archivo de una carpeta en Python 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/546694/c%c3%b3mo-cargar-un-archivo-de-una-carpeta-en-python-3). Si la pregunta que eliminé los moderadores la pueden de nuevo publicar, porfavor cambien la explicación de porque fue cerrada la pregunta, no sé porque esa explicación si la pregunta fue resuelta y quien me comentó me dio la respuesta.

Comment: Buen día, esta sería una pregunta para [meta] no para [es.so] por lo que tal vez esta pregunta termine cerrada, pero si vas a tu perfil en la sección de Actividad > Preguntas, hasta abajo hay una liga para mostrar las preguntas eliminadas, ahí la podrías recuperar (Hasta abajo de la pregunta aparece la opción).

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-la-eliminaci%c3%b3n-de-publicaciones-por-qu%c3%a9-podr%c3%ada-eliminarse-una-p)

Comment: Ya voté para recuperarla, faltan 6 votos más pero si lo ve un moderador lo podría recuperar de una,

Comment: HeytalePazguato ya fue migrada a meta, no sabía que existía meta, bueno ahora miro si puedo hacer, y si la puedo recuperar.

Comment: fedorqui Si la había leído, después pensé que no debí eliminarla, ahora quiero recuperar, ese pregunta que eliminé.

Comment: Carlos Muñoz gracias, ojalá la pueda recuperar.

Comment: HeytalePazguato ya la recupere, no veía esa opción desde el cel.

Comment: Evita borrar las cosas a menos que no sean útiles (para ti, para otros en el futuro que estén con la misma duda que tú actualmente). Para las preguntas, es un poco egoista quitarle a la gente en el futuro la opción de leer tu pregunta y ver lo que otros comentan o responden. Sobre los comentarios de cierre, eso da para otro post aquí en meta que seguro puede ser edificante :)

Comment: Si claro, yo borre la pregunta porque no me gusto el mensaje cuando cerraron la pregunta, la pregunta había sido resuelta y el que la cerro no se porque escribió ese mensaje y por eso la borre, luego la quise recuperar por si otros tienen la misma duda.