# ¿Qué hacemos con el incremento de preguntas que piden código sin haber intentado?

Tags: discusión, preguntas

En las últimas semanas he visto un incremento notable de preguntas del tipo:

> Hola, ¿Cómo hago < Inserte cualquier cosa sin código que demuestre haber intentado algo >? ¿Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

Aquí un par de ejemplos:

- [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109370/c%c3%b3mo-redireccionar-direcciones-con-controladores-repetidos-en-codeigniter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/109370/822)
- [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109372/c%c3%b3mo-usar-onchange-de-un-select-en-jquery-para-abrir-una-modal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/109372/822)

Considerando que carecen de código y teniendo en cuenta que potencialmente entran en la categoría de pregunta demasiado amplia y/o pregunta basada en opiniones, me gustaría saber **qué podríamos hacer para mejorar esta situación**.

Una posible solución es aumentar el número de comentarios en preguntas "sin código" que invite al usuario a ir por el recorrido y al enlace de cómo preguntar.

Se me ha ocurrido crear un pequeño bot scrapper que recorra las preguntas y les ponga comentarios utilizando nuestras cuentas (algo similar al usuario Comunidad), desconozco si esto se puede mediante la API de StackExange y si esto es legal en términos de la buena conducta de SOes.

En caso esto sea legal y evite atentar con la buena fe de SOes, si alguien desea colaborar con el desarrollo de esta idea, comente por favor. Las ideas en equipo se desarrollan mejor hasta hacerlas realidad :D

Comment: Además del tema de la pregunta me llaó la atención que se muestre el título de las preguntas, así que ví el markdown ¿alguna razón de poner los enlaces como lo has hecho? Por cierto, el segundo caso ya cuenta con código :)

Comment: Me parece muy interesante la situación que compartes, en particular porque no he estado muy activo por acá los meses recientes. Según entiendo no es obligatorio que toda pregunta tenga código, por otro lado, el usar algo como un bot scrapper y que agregue comentarios pareciera un proyecto técnicamente interesante, en particular si se incluye IA, pero me parece que va en contra de uno de los pilares del modelo que es el que los miembros hacemos la moderación. Me inclino más por alternativas que apoyen a los miembros a hacer las tareas de moderador de forma mas efectiva, ...

Comment: Se me viene a la mente herramientas como userscripts o extensiones de navegador.

Comment: excelente aporte hermano, una extensión que tenga el comentario pre-escrito listo para dar click en comentar automáticamente :D

Comment: Comentaros que existen extensiones de navegador para añadir comentarios automatizados, por ejemplo [AutoReviewComments](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoreviewcomments/bcfoamnigomkoaaiceppbbdlembpeejc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Comment: excelente aporte @Pikoh!

Comment: Cómo hacer para que, además, NO RESPONDAN haciendo de servicio de redacción de código?

Answer (score 3):

Desde mi punto de vista, en el contexto actual no hay mucho por hacer, solo intentar guiar a los usuarios a que revisen la temática del sitio, tomen el recorrido o revisen cómo preguntar y sobre todo animarlos a están en el lugar adecuado para externar sus dudas y problemáticas de programación.

Ya existe una pregunta en Meta donde se encuentra una extensa [Lista de comentarios para ayudar a los nuevos usuarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios) y que podemos tomar y hemos tomado como referencia, ya que son respuestas genéricas y en su mayoría se expresa cortesía.

Mientras llega un valiente que haga una extensión<sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>Mariano o Fredy :)</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup> para tomar esos comentarios como referencia creo que podemos abrir esa pregunta y tomarlos directamente.

Dado que no es comportamiento uniforme creo que se debe tratar como tal, algo con lo que podemos lidiar dejando un comentario. Si este comportamiento se llegara a incrementar durante dos meses o más igual y podríamos acudir a los señores moderadores o al gerente de la comunidad para proponer ciertas soluciones como procesos automáticos.

Comment: La idea del bot me sigue dando vueltas la cabeza :D y ahora con tu aporte y la idea del buen @Ruben, una extensión caería excelente. Sería algo como: click derecho, elegir comentario y boom :D

Comment: El problema está en los que preguntan con cero esfuerzo para intentar algo, cualquier cosa, y los que gustosos les proveen código para "que prueben". Así no hay cómo.

Comment: @Alfabravo debido a que es una comunidad moderada por los mismos usuarios, es algo que no hay forma de evitar y seguirá sucediendo a lo largo del tiempo que dure esta comunidad

Comment: @Phi y si es así, por qué en SO en inglés sí fue posible ordenar esto?

Comment: @Alfabravo me temo que no, siguen apareciendo cosas del mismo tipo, no es algo que se pueda ver a simple vista porque SO en inglés ya tiene un nivel de madurez mucho mayor y además con las más de 7k preguntas diarias existe un filtrado automático

Comment: @Phi no estoy de acuerdo. Es verdad que hay más moderadores trabajando en diferentes husos horarios, pero todo comienza por los otros usuarios esperando un mínimo esfuerzo de los otros. Las preguntas se marcan On hold rápidamente. Entonces sí, depende de la comunidad.