# ¿Sería posible agregar la opción "anotar" en el menú bajo las preguntas para agilizar comentarlas cuando deben recibir observaciones?

Tags: característica-nueva, comentarios, interfaz-de-usuario

Hace un par de días estuve leyendo una pregunta acerca de la creación de una lista (banco) de comentarios predefinidos para ayudar a nuevos usuarios. Y, la verdad, me motivó a participar proponiendo una característica, ignorando si existe o no (en mi calidad de usuario nuevo y con muy baja puntuación, ignoro mucho acerca de las características de **SOes**).

La idea es la siguiente: dado el menú `compartir | editar | reportar` situado bajo las preguntas:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sugiero agregarle la opción `anotar`, que tendría el siguiente comportamiento:

- desplegaría un menú emergente (popup) bajo el ratón con una lista de categorías de respuesta posibles (por ejemplo las que se proponen en [Lista de comentarios para ayudar a los nuevos usuarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/475/91033)).
- Al seleccionar un elemento de la lista, se lanzaría una solicitud Ajax que mostraría en una capa emergente (layer modal) una tabla con las respuestas preparadas para el caso; un click sobre alguna de ellas la pasaría a la caja de edición de comentarios (como si se hubiese elegido la opción "agregar comentario") para que el usuario que fuera a ofrecer el comentario o a hacer la pregunta orientadora la editara y ajustara al caso.

Por [sugerencia de @Rubén](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios/3542#comment12643_3542) estuve visitando [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) e hice un recorrido que podría eventualmente llamarse juicioso. Encontré que se puede hacer uso de metatags para insertar algunos comentarios; pero, si uno no recuerda funciones y objetos de los lenguajes con que "gana la manduca" menos aún un grupo significativo de metatags. Percibir que podría ser útil, aunado a una amable sugerencia de @fedorqui me impulsaron a proponer esta característica.

Me encantaría que sea posible.

Comment: Yo utilizo [SE-AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments) que es una extension que te permite editar la lista de comentarios que puedan repetirse. Incluso organizarlos para que salgan solo los aplicables a preguntas, o solo respuestas. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b La idea apunta hacia contar con una funcionalidad instalada, que haga innecesario instalar extensiones en los navegadores. Acabo de entrar al repositorio que indicas y, me parece (no he verificado), que se trata de eso, que dista mucho de lo que se propone.

Comment: Entiendo que quieres una funcionalidad propia del sitio pero no creo que la vayan a implementar. De ser necesaria, habría que proponerse en Meta SO ya que es el sitio donde primero lanzan las nuevas funcionalidades y luego en el resto de sitios

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias por la edición. Precisó mucho la formulación!

Comment: @lois6b Voy a tratar de llevarla, aunque mi inglés escrito, es muy pobre. ¿No habrá problema por el hecho de haber sido posteada, con anterioridad, en un hilo de SE?

Comment: por haber sido publicado aquí? Ningún problema