# ¿Cómo mejorar la experiencia de nuevos usuarios?

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos

Buen día,

Este año estuve participando mucho en el sitio y me he dado cuenta que hay "olas" de nuevos usuarios (Supongo que coincide con los meses de exámenes o entrega de proyectos de las escuelas) y he notado que cada vez es más frecuente encontrar preguntas mal formuladas, ya sea por que piden que alguien les haga el trabajo (O no se apegan a las normas del sitio de alguna forma) o que les hace falta mucha información y no son claras.

El problema es que con la escaces de buenas preguntas, la tendencia de algunos usuarios es responder las preguntas del tipo "haganlo por mi".

Al final, las preguntas mal realizadas por lo general terminan cerradas y/o con votos negativos, en algunos casos ignoradas y/o con comentarios sugiriendo que editen la pregunta. Esto proboca que el usuario que publicó la pregunta tenga en general una mala experiencia ya que su pregunta no fue resuelta por X o por Y.

¿Existe forma de forzar a los nuevos usuarios a que no puedan publicar sin haber leido [ask] y [tour]?

¿Existe forma de introducir una sección como de "revisión" donde los nuevos usuarios califiquen si las preguntas están bien hechas o no?

Otros daños colaterales es que cuando se presenta una de estas "olas" de nuevos usuarios se genera mucho contenido "basura" como respuestas que deberían ser comentarios, respuestas del tipo "yo también tengo este problema", etc...

Me gustaría leer sugerencias de algunos usuarios para saber como podemos mejorar la participación y experiencia para nuevos usuarios.

Comment: "¿Existe forma de introducir una sección como de "revisión" donde los nuevos usuarios califiquen si las preguntas están bien hechas o no?": más o menos, es el _Triage_ de SO. Pero no está implementado aquí, al menos hasta ahora :(

Comment: Bueno a mi parecer para un usuario nuevo que solo se toma la molestia de hacer copy/paste de su ejercicio para que otros se la resuelvan será peor experiencia que no se le permita publicar hasta que lea el *tour* y *ask*, cualquier usuario que tiene interés se esfuerza por resolver sus ejercicios, para mí los que solo ponen el encabezado es porque simplemente no les interesa y por ende le darán al botón **next** sin haber leído nada aunque sea obligatorio. Es difícil aceptar este comportamiento de algunos usuarios, y veo que es complicado controlar eso, o al menos eso es lo que pienso. ;)

Comment: Ahora sobre el como podemos mejorar este aspecto, mmm creo que no solo depende de nosotros si no también de los usuarios nuevos y que tan dispuestos estén para seguir las normas del sitio.

Comment: Yo voy a decir algo impopular. Quizás lo mejor es dejar de responsabilizar a los usuarios nuevos y mejorar la actitud de los usuarios viejos.  El usuario nuevo se equivocará en publicar si o si y eso hay que aceptarlo, pero seguramente sus otras publicaciones irán mejorando. Pero cuando realizas una publicación que debe ser mejorada considero que a veces incurrimos en formas poco amigables en los comentarios, que si bien pueden ser educadas no son acogedoras, tampoco ayuda el que varios usuarios dejen el mismo mensaje, porque parece un ataque. Así el nuevo usuario no tiene ganas de volver y ..

Comment: convertirse en un usuario viejo. Con esto no quiero decir que hay que aceptar cualquier publicación. Pero sí que hay algunos usuarios tienen un estándar demasiado alto y se sienten que el resto de los usuarios estamos obligados a respetar ese estándar no escrito, esto considero no beneficia al sitio ni a la comunidad. Hay publicaciones que cualquiera puede mejorarla y no se hace, es más fácil criticar y/o votar negativo. Las preguntas son la semillas que alimentan el sitio, las respuesta son lo que atraen a los usuarios, hacer de policía viene después.

Comment: @Yussef, el problema es que si desde el principio no se les enseña a utilizarla de forma correcta es peor intentar cambiar la actitud de la gente, por eso es mejor corregir desde el inicio.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato lo que me señalas es el argumento que tienen algunos en el sitio, pero es incomprobable que sea como ustedes dicen. La mía es que muchos se frustran y no vuelven, es decir esa "educación" no sirvió para nada.  No obstante, no estoy diciendo que no se les pueda pedir que mejoren la publicación, yo apelo a un asunto de forma, muchos(y me incluyo) hemos dejado un comentario poco acogedor a una mala pregunta, o si ya tiene un comentario que le dice que está mal ¿para qué agregar otro? Aquí un ejemplo de un buen comentario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/574619/301324

Comment: @Yussef, estoy muy de acuerdo en que no esta bien bombardear al usuario con comentarios, si alguien dejó un comentario solo dar +1 estaría bien, pero si considero que el usuario nuevo tiene gran parte o toda la responsabilidad cuando realiza una pregunta mal formulada, sobre todo cuando no agrega detalles para resolver el problema que tiene, creo que por sentido común cuando necesitas ayuda sabes que tienes que agregar la **mejor explicación posible** y el código necesario. ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM Es que en un mundo ideal sería como tú dices. En la práctica, poco podemos hacer ante un usuario nuevo, existe una curva de aprendizaje del sitio y eso hay que asumirlo. Es más realista, aunque de todas maneras difícil, proponer cambios de nosotros (los usuarios activos) que puedan mejorar la situación. Por otro lado no es un asunto solo de las preguntas, también atañe a las respuestas, un usuario nuevo publica una respuesta correcta pero incompleta y le caen los comentarios y negativos, cuando en la misma ayuda dice que la respuesta no tiene por qué ser perfecta

Comment: ¿Qué porcentaje de usuarios hace más de una o dos preguntas?

Comment: Eso si no sé, tal vez algún moderador lo pueda ver, pero más bien yo creo que sería interesante saber el porcentaje que escribe respuestas, porque ese es el momento en que los usuarios en verdad se empiezan a involucrar con el sitio.

Comment: En Stackoverflow cuando vas a hacer tu primera pregunta te pregunta muchas cosas y te dice ¿Qué has intentado? Eso estaría bien que se implementase para evitar preguntas basadas en un enunciado.

Comment: Pero no sé si alguien de la comunidad en español tenga las credenciales para modificar el proceso o si eso es igual para todos los sitios

Comment: pueden agregar un modulo de preguntas solo para usuarios de bajo nivel como yo, y no se mesclen con usuarios de alto nivel de puntos. y dar insentivos para que usiarios de alto nivel revicen esas preguntas. Asi no se mexclan todas las preguntas y el usuario de alto nivel que las lea las preguntas sabra q veras errores y asi.

Comment: @wally, en lo personal creo que ambas partes se benefician de estar en la misma plataforma pero creo que el esfuerzo actual por la mayoría de usuarios nuevos no ha sido suficiente ya que muchos no leen nada al crear una cuenta. Pero los que sí lo hacen y crean buenas preguntas se benefician rápidamente al obtener y compartir conocimiento con la comunidad.

Comment: creo que la respuesta es sensilla y simple ... se cierran las preguntas mal hechas y se espera que el usuario (interesado) arregle la pregunta... de esta forma se sabe que ya ha leido algo del centro de ayuda ... si estas muy interesado en el usuario puedes dejarle comentarios de como hacer para mejorar su pregunta ...

Comment: en cuanto a las respuesta mal formuladas, o respuesta dadas a una mala pregunta... la respuesta tambien es sensilla... bombardeamos la respuesta con **votos negativos** hasta que el usuario entienda que esta mal lo que hizo ... si el usuario esta interesado en mejorar, eliminara o editara su respuesta.

Comment: en todo caso si los usuarios no estan **interesados** en mejorar, apoyar a la comunidad y seguir las normas del sitio ... no nos hacen falta ... y asi se controla la calidad del sitio... como fue diseñado el sistema.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 No podría estar más en desacuerdo, el voto indiscriminado está prohibido, no puedes tratar de hacer cumplir las reglas incumpliendo las reglas, y además tú mismo tienes una publicación reclamando sobre el voto negativo fuera de norma.

Comment: @Yussef exacto ... y adivina que ... nadie hizo nada ... y la comunidad sigue por lo que veo en su libre alberdrio ... haciendo lo que mejor le paresca ... y como dijo alguien en su momento ... si me gane el privilegio de botar usare mis votos y mis puntos de reputacion como mejor me parescan ...

Comment: @ArcanisGK507, pero si la forma como "mejor te parezca" no está dentro de los lineamientos tampoco es correcto.

Comment: digancelo a la comunidad ... es como actua ... lo veo todos los dias a cada rato ...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Lista de comentarios para ayudar a los nuevos usuarios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/475/lista-de-comentarios-para-ayudar-a-los-nuevos-usuarios)

Comment: Yo no quiero gente vaga en este sitio. Si se niegan a entender que tienen que intentar algo (incluso si se les deja un comentario) y lo indican asi los lineamientos del sitio, entonces tengo mas que motivo suficiente para votar el cierre. A mi no me pagan para ayudarlos.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 eso no es cierto, al menos para la sección Python. Por cierto, bienvenido de vuelta!